# How can I make my vertical css marquee repeat

Tags: html, css, marquee

I'm trying to make a vertical marquee loop without any whitespace/gaps but I can't seem to make it repeat. I added `aria-hidden="true"` which worked on my horizontal marquee but doesn't seem to be the fix this time.

here is a code pen with the marquee: https://codepen.io/theomarusman/pen/oNbBgej

[this is the white space i want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6fGe.png)

Edit: the row and col tags are useless I'm using code from another marquee to make this one and there I used it in a row and col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
/* Please try this instead */

body {
 background-color: black;
}

.side-bar {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 color: white;
 writing-mode: vertical-rl;
 text-orientation: sideways-right;
}

.marquee p {
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 height: 100%;
}

.marquee span {
 animation: marquee 8s linear infinite;
 display: inline-flex;
 padding-right: 10px;
 font-size: 4rem;
}

@keyframes marquee {
 from {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
 }

 to {
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
}
```

```html
    <div class="position-fixed side-bar">
      <div class="row marquee">
        <div class="col-12 bg-white">
          <p class="m-0 p-0 p-3">
            <span class="m-0 p-0 pb-4" aria-hidden="true">USE CODE "MLT"</span>
            <span class="m-0 p-0 pb-4" aria-hidden="true">USE CODE "MLT"</span>
            <span class="m-0 p-0" aria-hidden="true">USE CODE "MLT"</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}
```

This code changes to the following.

```
.marquee p{
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height:100%;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

Solved in codepen

https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/OJMWMpm

More examples are

[Horizontal marquee without white space and JS](https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/JjGEYRZ)

[Vertical marquee without white space and JS](https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/eYJgpVy)

Comment: I think you do not understand me. I said that you can delete your upvote from [**this bad question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63463993), please. ;-)