# How to show names of departments in SVG map of France on mouse click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a map of **France** in SVG, on each `path` I put `data-name` that I would like to retrieve and display in a modal when clicking on a department.
Do you have any idea how I might do this?

```html
<path data-nom="Paris" data-numerodepartement="75" class="region-11 departement departement-75 departement-paris" d=...
```

Here is a piece of JavaScript code that displays the selected `data-name` in the log, I think it can help :

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      map = this.getElementById('map');
      paths = map.getElementsByTagName('path');

      for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        paths[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
          console.log("Dpt: "+e.target.getAttribute('data-nom'));

        })
      }
    });
```

This is my SVG:

```html
    <svg id="map" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 667 578" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
        <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
            <g id="france" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(0.000000, 1.000000)">
                <g id="complete_map" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup">
                    <path data-nom="Guadeloupe" id="div1" data-numerodepartement="971" class="region-01 departement departement-971 departement-guadeloupe" d="M35.87,487.13l0.7,7.2l-4.5-1.1l-2,1.7l-5.8-0.6l-1.7-1.2l4.9,0.5l3.2-4.4L35.87,487.13z M104.87,553.63 l-4.4-1.8l-1.9,0.8l0.2,2.1l-1.9,0.3l-2.2,4.9l0.7,2.4l1.7,2.9l3.4,1.2l3.4-0.5l5.3-5l-0.4-2.5L104.87,553.63z M110.27,525.53 l-6.7-2.2l-2.4-4.2l-11.1-2.5l-2.7-5.7l-0.7-7.7l-6.2-4.7l-5.9,5.5l-0.8,2.9l1.2,4.5l3.1,1.2l-1,3.4l-2.6,1.2l-2.5,5.1l-1.9-0.2 l-1,1.9l-4.3-0.7l1.8-0.7l-3.5-3.7l-10.4-4.1l-3.4,1.6l-2.4,4.8l-0.5,3.5l3.1,9.7l0.6,12l6.3,9l0.6,2.7c3-1.2,6-2.5,9.1-3.7l5.9-6.9 l-0.4-8.7l-2.8-5.3l0.2-5.5l3.6,0.2l0.9-1.7l1.4,3.1l6.8,2l13.8-4.9L110.27,525.53z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Martinique" data-numerodepartement="972" class="region-02 departement departement-972 departement-martinique" d="m44.23,433.5l1.4-4.1l-6.2-7.5l0.3-5.8l4.8-4 l4.9-0.9l17,9.9l7,8.8l9.4-5.2l1.8,2.2l-2.8,0.8l0.7,2.6l-2.9,1l-2.2-2.4l-1.9,1.7l0.6,2.5l5.1,1.6l-5.3,4.9l1.6,2.3l4.5-1.5 l-0.8,5.6l3.7,0.2l7.6,19l-1.8,5.5l-4.1,5.1h-2.6l-2-3l3.7-5.7l-4.3,1.7l-2.5-2.5l-2.4,1.2l-6-2.8l-5.5,0.1l-5.4,3.5l-2.4-2.1 l0.2-2.7l-2-2l2.5-4.9l3.4-2.5l4.9,3.4l3.2-1.9l-4.4-4.7l0.2-2.4l-1.8,1.2l-7.2-1.1l-7.6-7L44.23,433.5z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Guyane" data-numerodepartement="973" class="region-03 departement departement-973 departement-guyane" d="m95.2,348.97l-11.7,16.4l0.3,2.4l-7.3,14.9 l-4.4,3.9l-2.6,1.3l-2.3-1.7l-4.4,0.8l0.7-1.8l-10.6-0.3l-4.3,0.8l-4.1,4.1l-9.1-4.4l6.6-11.8l0.3-6l4.2-10.8l-8.3-9.6l-2.7-8 l-0.6-11.4l3.8-7.5l5.9-5.4l1-4l4.2,0.5l-2.3-2l24.7,8.6l9.2,8.8l3.1,0.3l-0.7,1.2l6.1,4l1.4,4.1l-2.4,3.1l2.6-1.6l0.1-5.5l4,3.5 l2.4,7L95.2,348.97z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="La Réunion" data-numerodepartement="974" class="region-04 departement departement-974 departement-la-reunion" d="m41.33,265.3l-6.7-8.5l1.3-6l4.1-2.4l0.7-7.9 l3.3,0.4l7.6-6.1l5.7-0.8l21,4l5,5.3v4.1l7.3,10.1l6.7,4.5l1,3.6l-3.3,7.9l0.9,9.6l-3.4,3.5l-17.3,2.9l-19.6-6.5l-3.8-3.6l-4.7-1.2 l-0.9-2.5l-3.6-2.3L41.33,265.3z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Mayotte" data-numerodepartement="976" class="region-06 departement departement-976 departement-mayotte" d="m57.79,157.13l11.32,5.82l-3.24,7.46l-5.66,7.52l5.66,8.37l-4.04,5.7l-5.66,8.01l5.66,4.37l-7.28,4.37l-8.09-2.73l-4.04-5.04v-4.85l-3.24-6.55l7.28,3.88l4.04,1.13v-7.14l-4.85-8.43v-14.8l-8.09-2.61l-3.24-2.67v-5.76l8.9-6.79l7.28,10.19L57.79,157.13z M78.07,164.38l-5.56,3.42l4.81,5.59l3.93-4.79L78.07,164.38z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Paris" data-numerodepartement="75" class="region-11 departement departement-75 departement-paris" d="M641.8,78.3l-0.2,3.8l-1,2.6l-8.3-1.7l-6-0.6l-5.2,3h-4l-2.5-0.3l-0.4-0.1l-13.5-5l-3-3.8l-4.3-1.9l-0.5-0.2 l0.4-1.9l1.3-3.1l2.7-2.1l2.9-1.1l3.9,0.5h0.1l0.9-2.2l7.1-4.6l14-0.1l1.8,3.6l1.8,2.4l0.6,0.9l0.1,0.4L631,68l0.4,5.4l0.4,1.8v0.1 l-0.3,0.8l0.1,3.6l0.6-0.5l1.6-1.6l2-0.5l2-0.5L641.8,78.3z M396.8,154.7l-3.2-0.5l-2.5,1.7l3,3.5l5.3-0.1l-1.8-1.9L396.8,154.7z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Seine-et-Marne" data-numerodepartement="77" class="region-11 departement departement-77 departement-seine-et-marne" d="m441.1,176.1l-2.9,0.8l0.4,8.5l-15.4,3 l-0.2,5.8l-3.9,5.4l-11.2,2.7l-9.2-0.7l2.6-1.5l0.6-2.7l-4.2-4.3L397,190l3.4-4.8l4-17.2l-0.5-1l1.1-4.1l-0.3-2.9v-0.1l-1.3-4.7 l1.3-2.5l-1.7-5.1l0.1-0.1l1.7-2.3l-0.2-2l6.9,1l2-2.2l2.5,1.6l8.1-2.9l2.6,0.7l1.8,2.5l-0.7,2.8l3.9,4.2l9.3,6l-0.4,2l-2.6,2.2 l3.5,8.3l2.6,1.7L441.1,176.1z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Yvelines" data-numerodepartement="78" class="region-11 departement departement-78 departement-yvelines" d="m364.1,158.1l-3.6-6.6l-1.8-5.8l2.3-2.6 l3.8,0.1l9.5,0.8l9,3.6l5.5,6.1l-2,3.1l3.2,5.2l-7.1,5.4l-1.6,2.6l0.7,2.9l-4.6,8.6l-3.1,0.7L372,180l-1.2-5.6l-6.2-5.4L364.1,158.1z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Essonne" data-numerodepartement="91" class="region-11 departement departement-91 departement-essonne" d="m401.6,164.8l2.3,2.2l0.5,1l-4,17.2L397,190 l-3.7-0.6l-2.8,1.8l-1.5-2.7l-1.9,2.9l-6.9,0.7l-2.8-10.6l4.6-8.6l-0.7-2.9l1.6-2.6l7.1-5.4v-0.1l3.7,1.6l5.1,2.1L401.6,164.8z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Hauts-de-Seine" data-numerodepartement="92" class="region-11 departement departement-92 departement-hauts-de-seine" d="M391.1,155.9l3,3.5l-0.4,4.1l-3.7-1.6v0.1l-3.2-5.2l2-3.1l3.6-2.6l1.3,2l-0.1,1.1L391.1,155.9z M612.6,54.1 l1.6-0.7l0.7-1.9l0.5-1.8l-0.1-1.1l-0.2-1.4l-4.6-1.9l-4.6-0.9l-4,1.3l-7.6,5.6l-6.1,5.8l-5.3,3l-1,1l-3.75,7.4l1.79,7.17 l-0.06,0.07l0.01,0.06l-2.74,3.23l0.68,2.44l2.5,4.8l3.3-0.5l1,5.2l3.9-0.3l1.4,3.5l3.4,1.6l0.5,2.1l5.3,4.2l4.3,1.3l-0.1,4.9 l5.7,3.5l3.15-5.91l-0.7-5.46l0.72-1.2l0.4-1.3l0.7-2.1l-1.4-1.9l0.3-1.2l0.8-2.8l-1-2.6l0.5-0.3l0.5-0.3l0.9-0.5l0.7-1.1l-0.4-0.1 l-13.5-5l-3-3.8l-4.3-1.9l-0.5-0.2l0.3-1.9l1.4-3.1l2.7-2.1l2.8-1.1h0.1l3.9,0.5l0.9-2.2l7.2-4.6l-0.7-2l-0.6-2l1.4-0.7L612.6,54.1z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Seine-Saint-Denis" data-numerodepartement="93" class="region-11 departement departement-93 departement-seine-saint-denis" d="M404.7,152.7l-1.3,2.5l1.3,4.7v0.1l-7.1-2.6l-0.8-2.7l-3.2-0.5l0.1-1.1l-1.3-2l3.3-1.3l2.6,1.1 c1.6-1.1,3.2-2.2,4.7-3.3L404.7,152.7z M663.2,73.89l0.06-0.08l-0.02-0.04l2.61-3.38l-3.95-0.3l-1.6-5.9l0.06-0.06l-0.02-0.06 l6.36-6.56l0.1-5.42l1.1-4l-1.2-3.4l-5.1-8l0.07-0.08l-0.03-0.04l2.65-3.33l-0.89-4.04l-4.5-2.9l-4.1,1.7l-6.4,8.8l-8.2,6.2 l-0.7-0.2l-7.8-1.1l-1.9,1l-5.1-4.6l-1.3-0.2l-1.9-0.7l-5.1,3l-1.6,2.7l-1-1.2l-5.9-2.1l-1.96,2.25v0.2l0.66,2.45l3.9,0.8l4.7,1.9 l0.1,1.4l0.1,1.1l-0.2,0.9l-0.3,0.9l-0.7,1.9l-1.6,0.7l-0.3,0.8l-1.4,0.7l0.6,2l0.7,2l13.9-0.2l0.1,0.1l1.8,3.6l1.8,2.4l0.6,0.8 l0.1,0.5L631,68l0.4,5.4l0.4,1.8l5.9-0.5l0.5-0.3c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0l6.3-2.8l2.9,0.4l0.7,1.3l3,1.5l4,2.9c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2 l0.7,0.5l6,6.2l0.8,0.6c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1l3.6,2.6l0.04-0.13l0.43-1.3l0.23-0.68l-1.8-6L663.2,73.89z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Val-de-Marne" data-numerodepartement="94" class="region-11 departement departement-94 departement-val-de-marne" d="M404.7,160l0.3,2.9l-1.1,4.1l-2.3-2.2l-2.8,0.8l-5.1-2.1l0.4-4.1l5.3-0.1l-1.8-1.9L404.7,160z M668.09,102.2 h0.06l-0.02-0.12l3.31-0.19l-1.55-3.58l-3.69-2.41l0.8-8h-0.1l-3.6-2.6c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1l-0.8-0.6l-6-6.2l-0.7-0.5 c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.2l-4-2.9l-3-1.5l-0.7-1.3l-2.9-0.4l-6.3,2.8c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0l-0.5,0.3l-5.9,0.5v0.1l-0.3,0.8l0.1,3.6 l0.6-0.5l1.6-1.7l2-0.4l2-0.5l4,1.7l-0.2,3.8l-1,2.6l-8.3-1.7l-6-0.6l-5.2,3h-4l-2.5-0.3l-0.6,1.1h-0.1l-0.9,0.5l-0.5,0.3l-0.5,0.3 l1,2.5v0.1l-0.8,2.8l-0.3,1.2l1.4,1.9l-0.7,2.1l-0.4,1.3l-0.7,1.2l0.78,5.38h0.06l2.1,0.2l4.7,2.8l3.1-2.2l0.1,5.5l3.3,2.4l4.9-1.8 l0.7,2.5l5.2-2.3l0.5,1.3l1.7,1.7l4.6-3.6l2.1-0.5l5.2-1.8l1.9,6.8l1.7,2.5l3.3,1.8l5.44,1.88l-0.68-5.05l0.05-0.08l-0.01-0.04 l2.5-4.2l2.73-2.74l-1.38-3.64l0.07-0.06l-0.03-0.07l2.35-1.96L668.09,102.2z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Val-d’Oise" data-numerodepartement="95" class="region-11 departement departement-95 departement-val-doise" d="m374.3,144l-9.5-0.8l4-9.5l1.6,3.2l5.6,1.1 l6.3-1.8l9.2,2.2l2.2-1.6l10.9,6.4l0.2,2l-1.7,2.3l-0.1,0.1c-1.5,1.1-3.1,2.2-4.7,3.3l-2.6-1.1l-3.3,1.3l-3.6,2.6l-5.5-6.1 L374.3,144z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Cher" data-numerodepartement="18" class="region-24 departement departement-18 departement-cher" d="m385.3,235.4l5-2.4l13.5,3.1l3.9,4.8l9-1.7l2,6.5l-1.7,5.8l2.7,2.1 l3.1,7.6l0.3,5.9l2.2,2l-0.2,5.8l-1.3,8.9h-0.1h-4l-4.8,3.7l-8.4,2.9l-2.3,1.9l1.7,5.3l-1.7,2.4l-8.7,1l-3.5,5.9v0.1l-4.9-0.2 l1.5-3.5l-0.9-8.9l-4.7-7.9l1.4-2.7l-2.3-2.2l2.5-5.1l-2.3-11.7l-11.6-1.6l2.8-5.5l2.8,0.1l0.6-2.8l9.7-2l-2.1-5.9l5.9-4.1 L385.3,235.4z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Eure-et-Loir" data-numerodepartement="28" class="region-24 departement departement-28 departement-eure-et-loir" d="m333.1,200.9l-2.1-3.8l-1.1-7.5l7.5-5.1 l-0.5-4.6l0.2-4.5l-4.8-4.4l-0.1-3.2l2.4-2.6l6-1.1l5.3-3.2l2.8,1.6l6-1.3l-0.2-2.8l6-6.9l3.6,6.6l0.5,10.9l6.2,5.4l1.2,5.6l2.3,2.2 l3.1-0.7l2.8,10.6l-0.5,1.5l-4.8,10.8l-8.5,0.6l-6,2.8l0.2,2.8l-3.3-1.9l-5.5,3.5L339,201.4l-6.3,1.3L333.1,200.9z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Indre" data-numerodepartement="36" class="region-24 departement departement-36 departement-indre" d="m357.8,308.5l-2.8,2.9l-1.7-2.5l-5.8,1.1 l-2.6-1.1l1.5-2.8l-2.5-1.3l-2.6-5.4h-2.9l-4.6-4.4l0.8-5.8l-2.1-3l5.6-0.5l-1-2.7l3.3-11.9l5.1-2.7l2.3,1.7l2.6-3.5l2.5-2.1l-1-4.9 l6-3.2l2.5,1.3l1.5-2.6l6.4-0.9l5.2,3.5l-2.8,5.5l11.6,1.6l2.3,11.7l-2.5,5.1l2.3,2.2l-1.4,2.7l4.7,7.9l0.9,8.9l-1.5,3.5l-2.7,0.8 l-13.2-2.7l-1.9,2.5L357.8,308.5z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Indre-et-Loire" data-numerodepartement="37" class="region-24 departement departement-37 departement-indre-et-loire" d="m303.9,263l-5.5-3.2v-0.1l5.8-15.3l1.7-9.3 l0.7-2.4l6.1,2.6l-0.5-3.3l2.8,0.3l7.7-4.5l10.5,0.5l-0.2,5.5l2.2-1.8l6,3.4l-0.7,2.7l3.4,5.1l-1.2,9.1l2.4,1.9l2.6-1.3l4.2,6.7 l1,4.9l-2.5,2.1l-2.6,3.5l-2.3-1.7l-5.1,2.7l-3.3,11.9l1,2.7l-5.6,0.5l-7.1-10l-0.3-3.1l-5.3-3l1.4,2.9l-10,0.4l-2.8-1.4l-1.3-6.1 l-2.9,0.3L303.9,263z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Loir-et-Cher" data-numerodepartement="41" class="region-24 departement departement-41 departement-loir-et-cher" d="m357.9,256.4l-6,3.2l-4.2-6.7l-2.6,1.3 l-2.4-1.9l1.2-9.1l-3.4-5.1l0.7-2.7l-6-3.4l-2.2,1.8l0.2-5.5l-10.5-0.5l0.6-3.5l3.2-1.1l6.3-10.6l-0.4-5.5l-1.7-2.2l2-2.1v-0.1 l6.3-1.3l12.8,10.8l5.5-3.5l3.3,1.9l2.5,7.1l-1.8,3.2l1.7,5.6l3-1.3l2.4,1.5l1.1,3.8l2.9,0.6l1.9-2.3l15.2,1.6l0.8,2.6l-5,2.4 l5.1,7.6l-5.9,4.1l2.1,5.9l-9.7,2l-0.6,2.8l-2.8-0.1l-5.2-3.5l-6.4,0.9l-1.5,2.6L357.9,256.4z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Loiret" data-numerodepartement="45" class="region-24 departement departement-45 departement-loiret" d="m393.3,189.4l3.7,0.6l0.7,3.1l4.2,4.3l-0.6,2.7 l-2.6,1.5l9.2,0.7l11.2-2.7l6.7,7.5l0.4,5.8l-4.6,4.9l1.1,2.9l-1.6,2.4l-5.3,3.3l3,2.8l2.2,6.9l-2.8,0.7l-1.5,2.4l-9,1.7l-3.9-4.8 l-13.5-3.1l-0.8-2.6l-15.2-1.6l-1.9,2.3l-2.9-0.6l-1.1-3.8l-2.4-1.5l-3,1.3l-1.7-5.6l1.8-3.2l-2.5-7.1l-0.2-2.8l6-2.8l8.5-0.6 l4.8-10.8l0.5-1.5l6.9-0.7l1.9-2.9l1.5,2.7L393.3,189.4z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Côte-d’Or" data-numerodepartement="21" class="region-27 departement departement-21 departement-cote-dor" d="m523.6,241.7l3.9,8.2l-1.2,1.3l-1.8,8.2 l-6.2,6.8l-1.1,4.1v-0.1l-15,1.5l-8.8,4.2l-5.6-6.3l-5.5-1.9l-1.3-2.6l-5.7-1.7l-2.4-2.6V260l0.4-3.2l-3.7-1.2l-1.3-6h0.1l-1.3-2.7 l1.3-8.1l6.7-10.4l-1.7-2.3l2.8-2.1l0.3-3.7l-3.1-3.9l1.9-3.1l2.2-2l6.1-0.9l4.7-3.9l3.9,0.5l3.5,0.7l0.5,2.7l2.6,1l-0.3,2.9 l2.9,0.3l1.8,2.2l1,3.1l-2.8,2.4l2.3,4.8l9.2,2l3,1.6v2.8l4.8-1.9h0.1l2.7-1.6l2,3l0.1,3.2l-4.6,4.1L523.6,241.7z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Doubs" data-numerodepartement="25" class="region-27 departement departement-25 departement-doubs" d="m590.1,245.2l-2.4,2.2l0.4,3l-4.8,6.2l-4.8,4 l-0.4,2.9l-2.5,2.7l-5.7,1.7l-0.3,0.3l-1.7,2.3l0.9,2.7l-0.7,4.5l0.5,2.5l-9.5,8.8l-2.9,5.2l-0.22,0.69l-3.68-3.49l3.6-7.4l2.1-2.3 l-4.2-4.1l-2.9-0.5l-5.8-10.1l-3,0.8l-1.5-2.5l-2,2.1l-1.2-2.5l3-5.1l-5.2-7.8l22.3-10.2l3-4.7l5.6-1.9l2.8,0.9l1.8-2.2l3.2-0.4 l0.5-2.8l5.9,0.8l0.2-0.1h0.1l5.9,2.7l-1.4,2.5l1.4,2.4l0.41-0.46l-0.11,0.16l-2.2,4.9l7-0.7L590.1,245.2z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Jura" data-numerodepartement="39" class="region-27 departement departement-39 departement-jura" d="m552.3,291.4l3.68,3.49L553.4,303l-5.3,7.2 l-5.5,3.2l-3.8,0.2l-0.4-2.8l-3.4-1.6l-4,4.4l-2.9,0.1l-0.1-3h-2.9l-4.3-7.7l2.8-1.1l-0.8-5.3l2.8-5l-2.2-8.7l-2.5-1.6l5-3.7 l-8.3-4.4l-0.4-2.9l1.1-4.1l6.2-6.8l1.8-8.2l1.2-1.3l2.3,2l5.4,0.1l5.2,7.8l-3,5.1l1.2,2.5l2-2.1l1.5,2.5l3-0.8l5.8,10.1l2.9,0.5 l4.2,4.1l-2.1,2.3L552.3,291.4z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Nièvre" data-numerodepartement="58" class="region-27 departement departement-58 departement-nievre" d="m462.8,250l5.5-0.4l1.3,6l3.7,1.2l-0.4,3.2v0.8 l-1.1,0.3l-2.7,0.4v1.3l-2.8,1l0.3,5.9l-2.1,1.7l4,7l-1.9,2.1l0.7,2.9l-11.3,5.7l-7-2.8l-5.9,6l-4.4-3.7l-2.8,1.7l-6.4-0.2l-5.7-6.3 l1.3-8.9l0.2-5.8l-2.2-2l-0.3-5.9l-3.1-7.6l-2.7-2.1l1.7-5.8l-2-6.5l1.5-2.4l2.8-0.7v0.1h3.4l7.4,4.8h6l4.6-4.3l3.9,5.6l5.5,3 l5.8-0.9l0.9,3.7l2.8-0.9L462.8,250z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Haute-Saône" data-numerodepartement="70" class="region-27 departement departement-70 departement-haute-saone" d="m579.1,225.9l1.4,5.5l-0.2,0.1l-5.9-0.8 l-0.5,2.8l-3.2,0.4l-1.8,2.2l-2.8-0.9l-5.6,1.9l-3,4.7L535.2,252l-5.4-0.1l-2.3-2l-3.9-8.2l-2.6-1.4l4.6-4.1l-0.1-3.2l-2-3l-2.7,1.6 h-0.1l1.2-2.5l6.6-3.9l2.1,1.8l3.2-1l0.3-8.3l2-2.4l2.9,0.3l2.3-3.2l-0.2-1.4l8-5.8l7,4.3l5.8-1.6l4.9,3.6l5.1-2.2l8.4,6.6l-2.3,5.7 L579.1,225.9z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Saône-et-Loire" data-numerodepartement="71" class="region-27 departement departement-71 departement-saone-et-loire" d="m517.2,270.2v0.1l0.4,2.9l8.3,4.4l-5,3.7 l2.5,1.6l2.2,8.7l-2.8,5l0.8,5.3l-2.8,1.1l-4.8-3.3l-5.4,1.3l-5.9-1.5l-5.9,20.9l-5.7-7.7l-1.6,2.3l-2.5-1.5l-2.2,1.6l-2.2-1.7 l-2.3,1.9l-0.29,2.91L482,318.2v0.1l-5.7,3.8l-2.1-2.1l-8,1.5l-5.2-3.3v-3l3.7-4.6l0.5-5.5l-1.6-2.4l-7.9-2.9l-6.7-13.5l7,2.8 l11.3-5.7l-0.7-2.9l1.9-2.1l-4-7l2.1-1.7l-0.3-5.9l2.8-1l2.7-1.7l1.1-0.3l2.4,2.6l5.7,1.7l1.3,2.6l5.5,1.9l5.6,6.3l8.8-4.2 L517.2,270.2z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Yonne" data-numerodepartement="89" class="region-27 departement departement-89 departement-yonne" d="m425.8,207.1l-6.7-7.5l3.9-5.4l0.2-5.8l15.4-3 l3.6,1.5l4.5,5.5l2.5,8.3l2-2.2l3.6,4.1l5,10.9l12.6-1.6l2.9,1.4l-1.9,3.1l3.1,3.9l-0.3,3.7l-2.8,2.1l1.7,2.3l-6.7,10.4l-1.3,8.1 l1.3,2.7h-0.1l-5.5,0.4l-1.5-2.8l-2.8,0.9l-0.9-3.7l-5.8,0.9l-5.5-3l-3.9-5.6l-4.6,4.3h-6l-7.4-4.8H421v-0.1l-2.2-6.9l-3-2.8 l5.3-3.3l1.6-2.4l-1.1-2.9l4.6-4.9L425.8,207.1z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Territoire de Belfort" data-numerodepartement="90" class="region-27 departement departement-90 departement-territoire-de-belfort" d="m580.3,215.9l0.9-0.6l7.6,5l0.5,9l2.8-0.2l2,5 l-0.1,0.1l-2.79,0.39l-1.11-0.39l-3.19,4.34L586.5,239l-1.4-2.4l1.4-2.5l-5.9-2.7h-0.1l-1.4-5.5l-1.1-4.3L580.3,215.9z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Calvados" data-numerodepartement="14" class="region-28 departement departement-14 departement-calvados" d="m316.9,148l-0.7,2.2l-5.6-1l-7,1.7l-7.2,5.4 l-2.9,0.3l-5.7-1.1l-2.6,1.7l-4.9-3l-6.4,2.3l-2.7-1.3l-0.9,2.7l-5.4,2.9l-9.7-2.1l-1.8-2.4l4.5-5.3l-1.6-2.3l8.1-4.9l-2.2-8.2 l2-2.6l-8.4-3.1l-0.5-6.6v-0.1l0.1-0.7l1.8,0.8l1.9-2.1l3.4-0.3l9.4,3.3l13.9,1.5l6.9,3.4l5.7-0.7l4.7-2.5l4.1-3.7l5.1-1.1l0.3,8.3 h2.9l-2.3,2.1l2.8,9.4l-1.4,3L316.9,148z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Eure" data-numerodepartement="27" class="region-28 departement departement-27 departement-eure" d="m316.4,153.4l-0.2-3.2l0.7-2.2l-2.3-4.1l1.4-3l-2.8-9.4l2.3-2.1h-2.9 l-0.3-8.3l1.7-0.4l0.28-0.1h1.52l-0.9-0.2l0.8-0.3l-1.29-0.3l5.89-2.4l7.6,5l3.4-0.7l4.9,3l-1.9,2.4l2.1,2.1l5.4,2.4l1.4-2.7 l8.2-2.5l4.8-7l13.1,3.3l3.5,8.4l-4,2.6l-4,9.5l-3.8-0.1l-2.3,2.6l1.8,5.8l-6,6.9l0.2,2.8l-6,1.3l-2.8-1.6l-5.3,3.2l-6,1.1l-2.4,2.6 l-3.4-2.1l1.7-2.3l-7.8-9.5L316.4,153.4z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Manche" data-numerodepartement="50" class="region-28 departement departement-50 departement-manche" d="m255.2,158.7l9.7,2.1l4.1,4.2l-1.8,6.7 l-3.6,4.5h-0.1l-8.6-0.8l-5.4-2.3l-7.1,4.8l-2.7-1l-4.7-9.6l1.9-0.2l4.8,0.4l2.5-1.1l0.5-2.2l-2.4,1.3l-5.1-5.6l-0.3-5.3l2-6.1 l-0.3-4.9l-1.8-3.6l0.4-7.4l1.5-2l-2.5,0.3l-2-5l0.3-2.2l-2.4-1.2l-2.9-4.1l-0.7-5.9l-1.4-1.9l1.8-1.8l0.1-2.8l-0.5-2.3l-2.2-1.1 l-1-2.5l2.1-0.2l11.9,4.2h2.4l4-2.6l5.1,0.6l1.8,1.7l0.9,2.7l-3.2,5.2l4,6.5l1.1,4.3l-0.1,0.7v0.1l0.5,6.6l8.4,3.1l-2,2.6l2.2,8.2 l-8.1,4.9l1.6,2.3l-4.5,5.3L255.2,158.7z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Orne" data-numerodepartement="61" class="region-28 departement departement-61 departement-orne" d="m266.9,179.9l-3.3-3.7l3.6-4.5l1.8-6.7 l-4.1-4.2l5.4-2.9l0.9-2.7l2.7,1.3l6.4-2.3l4.9,3l2.6-1.7l5.7,1.1l2.9-0.3l7.2-5.4l7-1.7l5.6,1l0.2,3.2l6.3,0.5l7.8,9.5l-1.7,2.3 l3.4,2.1l0.1,3.2l4.8,4.4l-0.2,4.5l0.5,4.6l-7.5,5.1l1.1,7.5l-3.2-0.7l-3.1-3.5l-2.9,1l-7.2-5l-1.6-8.4l-2.8-1.5l-11,5.9l-3-0.1 v-0.1v-2.9l-3.3-1.6l-1.9-6l-2.7-0.2l-0.7,2.7h-9.1l-6.7,3.3l-2.5-1.7L266.9,179.9z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Seine-Maritime" data-numerodepartement="76" class="region-28 departement departement-76 departement-seine-maritime" d="m314.41,119.8l-7.61-1.8l-1.2-2l-0.1-2.3 l4.4-9.7l13.8-7.4L326,95l10.3-2.1l4.8-1.8l2.4,0.3L352,87l5.11-4.09l11.79,9.99l3.4,8.4l-3.1,4.7l1.4,8.7l-1.3,8l-13.1-3.3l-4.8,7 l-8.2,2.5l-1.4,2.7l-5.4-2.4l-2.1-2.1l1.9-2.4l-4.9-3l-3.4,0.7l-7.6-5L314.41,119.8z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Aisne" data-numerodepartement="02" class="region-32 departement departement-02 departement-aisne" d="m450.3,82.6l16.7,4.6l2.91,0.94L470.6,94l-1.3,3.5l1.3,3.1l-5,7.2 l-2.7,0.3l0.3,14.3l-1,2.8l-5.3-1.8l-8,4l-1.2,2.6l3.2,8l-5.5,2.3l1.6,2.4l-0.8,2.7l2.5,1.3l-7.7,10.2l-9.3-6l-3.9-4.2l0.7-2.8 l-1.8-2.5l-2.6-0.7l2.1-1.7l-0.5-2.8l-2.9-1.1l-2.4,1.5l-0.7-2.9l3,0.2l-2.9-4.5l2.6-1.7l2.4-5.7l2.6-1.1l-2.2-1.8l0.8-4.5 l-0.4-10.2l-2.3-7l3.9-8.1l0.4-3.8l12.6-0.6l2.6-2.2l2.3,1.7L450.3,82.6z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Nord" data-numerodepartement="59" class="region-32 departement departement-59 departement-nord" d="m384.33,25.06l0.87-0.26l2,0.8l1.1-2.1l7.9-2.1 l2.9,0.3l4.4-1.9v-0.1l1.2,4.8l2.3,3.7l-1.6,1.9l0.6,0.8l1.2,5.8h3.4l2.7,5.1l3.1,1.5h2.1l0.6-2.4l8.1-3l3.8,7.5l0.1,1l1.3,5.2 l2,3.5h0.1l2.8,0.6l2.1-1.4l2.4-0.2l-0.5,2.2l2.2-0.7l2.8,1l1.8,4.4l-0.6,2.3l0.7,2.3l1.4,1.9l1.1-2.6l4.6-0.3l2.4,1.1L462,64l5.5,6 l2.3,0.2l-2.1,2.4l-1.4,4.7l2.6,0.2l1.4,3.3l-3.5,3.9l0.2,2.5l-16.7-4.6l-5.2,1.8l-2.3-1.7l-2.6,2.2l-12.6,0.6l-3.3-2.6l3.5-10.6 l-1.8-2.4l-3-0.4l0.7-2.7l-3.9-5.2l3.1-1.6l-3.8-5.3l-5.9-1l1-6.1l-1.3-2.5l-1.7,2.2l-11.6-0.5l-4.1-4.2l0.6-2.8l-5.5-2.6 L384.33,25.06z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Oise" data-numerodepartement="60" class="region-32 departement departement-60 departement-oise" d="m372.8,131.1l-3.5-8.4l1.3-8l-1.4-8.7l3.1-4.7 l4.1,3.7l3.1-1.2l14.4,2.2l12.8,6.7l8.6-6.8l10.3-1.5l0.4,10.2l-0.8,4.5l2.2,1.8l-2.6,1.1l-2.4,5.7l-2.6,1.7l2.9,4.5l-3-0.2l0.7,2.9 l2.4-1.5l2.9,1.1l0.5,2.8l-2.1,1.7l-8.1,2.9l-2.5-1.6l-2,2.2l-6.9-1l-10.9-6.4l-2.2,1.6l-9.2-2.2L376,138l-5.6-1.1l-1.6-3.2 L372.8,131.1z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Pas-de-Calais" data-numerodepartement="62" class="region-32 departement departement-62 departement-pas-de-calais" d="m379.8,68.9l7.1,5.8l12-2.5l-2.6,5.7L398,81 l2.5-3.1l8.4,3.5l0.8-2.8l2.8,4.6l2.4-1.7l0.8,3.2l8.6-1.8l3.5-10.6l-1.8-2.4l-3-0.4l0.7-2.7l-3.9-5.2l3.1-1.6l-3.8-5.3l-5.9-1 l1-6.1l-1.3-2.5l-1.7,2.2l-11.6-0.5l-4.1-4.2l0.6-2.8l-5.5-2.6l-6.27-12.14L372.6,28.5l-6.4,5.4l0.9,5.6l-1.7,4.6l0.6,6.7l2,4.2 l-1.7-1.4l-0.3,9.7l2.27,1.58l10.53,1.02L379.8,68.9z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Somme" data-numerodepartement="80" class="region-32 departement departement-80 departement-somme" d="m424.3,82.9l3.3,2.6l-0.4,3.8l-3.9,8.1l2.3,7 l-10.3,1.5l-8.6,6.8l-12.8-6.7l-14.4-2.2l-3.1,1.2l-4.1-3.7l-3.4-8.4l-11.79-9.99L359.5,81l3.4-6.6l1.9-1.1l0.1-0.1l1.4,1.8l3.5,0.3 l-5.6-6l1.2-5.1l2.9,0.7l-0.03-0.02l10.53,1.02l1,3l7.1,5.8l12-2.5l-2.6,5.7L398,81l2.5-3.1l8.4,3.5l0.8-2.8l2.8,4.6l2.4-1.7 l0.8,3.2L424.3,82.9z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Ardennes" data-numerodepartement="08" class="region-44 departement departement-08 departement-ardennes" d="m469.91,88.14l0.79,0.26l9.8,0.4l7.3-3.2l1.1-6 l4-3.8l2.8-0.2v3.8L494,81l-0.6,5.2l3.3,4.5l-1,2.4l0.6,3.1l1.4,1.9l3.3-0.9l4.3,2.4l2.8,3.8l4.9,0.6l2,1.7l-0.9,2.4l2.1-0.13 l-1.6,1.13l-2,2.7l-5.7-2.1l-1.9,2l0.8,8.8l-3.2,5.1l1.4,2.5l-4.2,3.6v0.1l-20.1-1.9l-9.8-6.6l-6.7-0.9l-0.3-14.3l2.7-0.3l5-7.2 l-1.3-3.1l1.3-3.5L469.91,88.14z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Aube" data-numerodepartement="10" class="region-44 departement departement-10 departement-aube" d="m442.2,186.9l-3.6-1.5l-0.4-8.5l2.9-0.8l3-5 l3.2,4.5l9,1.2v-3.3l9.5-7.6l6.5-0.9l3.1,0.5l0.4,6.1l2.6,2c1.9,0.8,3.8,1.5,5.6,2.3l2.5-1.5l3.3,1.1l-0.6,3.4l2.4,5.2l5.6,3 l0.5,9.9l-0.1,2.7l-5.6,2.5l0.2,4.8l-3.9-0.5l-4.7,3.9l-6.1,0.9l-2.2,2l-2.9-1.4l-12.6,1.6l-5-10.9l-3.6-4.1l-2,2.2l-2.5-8.3 L442.2,186.9z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Marne" data-numerodepartement="51" class="region-44 departement departement-51 departement-marne" d="m440.6,158.9l0.4-2l7.7-10.2l-2.5-1.3l0.8-2.7 l-1.6-2.4l5.5-2.3l-3.2-8l1.2-2.6l8-4l5.3,1.8l1-2.8l6.7,0.9l9.8,6.6l20.1,1.9l2.2,9l-1,4.1l2.6,1.3l-0.6,3.9l-3.1,1.1l-1.1,5.8 l3.2,4.6l0.5,4.1l-8.6,2.2l2.2,2.5l-2.3,2.2l0.7,2.9h-4.7l-3.3-1.1l-2.5,1.5c-1.8-0.8-3.7-1.5-5.6-2.3l-2.6-2l-0.4-6.1l-3.1-0.5 l-6.5,0.9l-9.5,7.6v3.3l-9-1.2l-3.2-4.5l-2.6-1.7l-3.5-8.3L440.6,158.9z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Haute-Marne" data-numerodepartement="52" class="region-44 departement departement-52 departement-haute-marne" d="m493.9,167.9l8.6-2.2l3.4,5.2l16.9,10.4 l-2.4,2.3l12.7,9.5l-1.7,8.6l5.5,4.7l0.2,3.1l2.7-1.1l1.3,2.5v0.1l0.2,1.4l-2.3,3.2l-2.9-0.3l-2,2.4l-0.3,8.3l-3.2,1l-2.1-1.8 l-6.6,3.9l-1.2,2.5l-4.8,1.9v-2.8l-3-1.6l-9.2-2l-2.3-4.8l2.8-2.4l-1-3.1l-1.8-2.2l-2.9-0.3l0.3-2.9l-2.6-1l-0.5-2.7l-3.5-0.7 l-0.2-4.8l5.6-2.5l0.1-2.7l-0.5-9.9l-5.6-3l-2.4-5.2l0.6-3.4h4.7l-0.7-2.9l2.3-2.2L493.9,167.9z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Meurthe-et-Moselle" data-numerodepartement="54" class="region-44 departement departement-54 departement-meurthe-et-moselle" d="m588.2,170.9l1.9,1.3l-1.5,0.4l-10.6,7.6l-6.1-1.6l-1.6-2.7l-5.3,3.8 l-6,1l-2.4-1.8l-5.4,2l-1.1,2.8l-5.7,0.7l-4.1-4.8l0.1-2.9l-5.8-0.6l0.2-2.9l-2.5-2l1.7-2.8l-1.3-8.6l2.2-13.8l0.9-2.7l-4.9-11.5 l1.5-5.9l-1.2-2.7l-4.4-4.8l-5.3,2l-0.7-5.3l4.8-1.7l2-1.9h6.8l2.54,2.31L539.6,124l2.5,1.6l1.2,3.6l-1.7,3.1l1,5.6l-2.8,0.1 l4.3,7.5l11.5,4l-0.3,2.9l2.7,5.1l8.5,1.5l5.3,3.9l14.4,5.3L588.2,170.9z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Meuse" data-numerodepartement="55" class="region-44 departement departement-55 departement-meuse" d="m516.2,107.97l1.2-0.07l1.5,1.6l1.9,5.6 l0.7,5.3l5.3-2l4.4,4.8l1.2,2.7l-1.5,5.9l4.9,11.5l-0.9,2.7l-2.2,13.8l1.3,8.6l-1.7,2.8l2.5,2l-0.2,2.9l-1.9,2.3l-3-0.5l-6.9,3.4 l-16.9-10.4l-3.4-5.2l-0.5-4.1l-3.2-4.6l1.1-5.8l3.1-1.1l0.6-3.9l-2.6-1.3l1-4.1l-2.2-9v-0.1l4.2-3.6l-1.4-2.5l3.2-5.1l-0.8-8.8 l1.9-2l5.7,2.1l2-2.7L516.2,107.97z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Moselle" data-numerodepartement="57" class="region-44 departement departement-57 departement-moselle" d="m539.6,124l-2.65-10.19l0.65,0.59h2.4l1.5,2.1 l2.3,0.7l2.3-0.5l1-2.3l2-1.2l2.2-0.2l4.5,2.3l4.9-0.1l3.1,3.8l2.3,1.9l-0.5,2l3.7,3.2l2.8,4.5v2.3l4.2,0.7l1.2-1.9l-0.3-2.4 l2.6-0.2l3.8,1.8l1.4,3.5l2.1-1.5l2.5,1.9l5.8-0.4l5.3-4.2l2.2,1.4l0.5,2.1l2.4,2.4l3.2,1.5h0.03l-1.73,4.4l-1.4,2.6l-8.9,0.3 l-9.1-4.6l-0.8-2.8l-5,10.8l5.5,2.4l-1.6,2.5l2.3,1.7l1.3-2.5l3,0.3l4.3,3.4l-3,13.3l-2.3,1.8l-3.4-0.3l-2-2.7l-14.4-5.3l-5.3-3.9 l-8.5-1.5l-2.7-5.1l0.3-2.9l-11.5-4l-4.3-7.5l2.8-0.1l-1-5.6l1.7-3.1l-1.2-3.6L539.6,124z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Bas-Rhin" data-numerodepartement="67" class="region-44 departement departement-67 departement-bas-rhin" d="m631.8,140.7l-2.8,9.4l-7.8,10.5l-2,1.5l-1.4,3.3l0.3,4.9l-2.4,7.2 l0.7,3.6l-1.5,2l-1.2,5.5l-3.16,6.23L605.9,193l-0.3-2.8l-8.5-5.6l-3.1-0.2l-5.2-2.2l1.3-10l-1.9-1.3l3.4,0.3l2.3-1.8l3-13.3 l-4.3-3.4l-3-0.3l-1.3,2.5l-2.3-1.7l1.6-2.5l-5.5-2.4l5-10.8l0.8,2.8l9.1,4.6l8.9-0.3l1.4-2.6l1.73-4.4l8.87,0.6l2.4-0.6 L631.8,140.7z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Haut-Rhin" data-numerodepartement="68" class="region-44 departement departement-68 departement-haut-rhin" d="m605.9,193l4.64,1.83l-0.04,0.07v5.3l1.6,1.9 l0.2,3.4l-2.2,11.1l0.1,6.7l1.8,1.5l0.6,3.5l-2.2,2l-0.2,2.3l-3.1,0.9l0.5,2.2l-1.5,1.6h-2.7l-3.8,1.4l-3-1.1l0.3-2.5l-2.4-1.1 l-0.4,0.1l-2-5l-2.8,0.2l-0.5-9l-7.6-5l2.8-2.4v-6.2l4.8-7.8l4.1-13.5l1.1-1l3.1,0.2l8.5,5.6L605.9,193z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Vosges" data-numerodepartement="88" class="region-44 departement departement-88 departement-vosges" d="m520.4,183.6l2.4-2.3l6.9-3.4l3,0.5l1.9-2.3 l5.8,0.6l-0.1,2.9l4.1,4.8l5.7-0.7l1.1-2.8l5.4-2l2.4,1.8l6-1l5.3-3.8l1.6,2.7l6.1,1.6l10.6-7.6l1.5-0.4l-1.3,10l5.2,2.2l-1.1,1 l-4.1,13.5l-4.8,7.8v6.2l-2.8,2.4l-0.9,0.6l-8.4-6.6l-5.1,2.2l-4.9-3.6l-5.8,1.6l-7-4.3l-8,5.8v-0.1l-1.3-2.5l-2.7,1.1l-0.2-3.1 l-5.5-4.7l1.7-8.6L520.4,183.6z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Loire-Atlantique" data-numerodepartement="44" class="region-52 departement departement-44 departement-loire-atlantique" d="m213.1,265.2l1.8-1l-2.8-4.1l-7.8-3l3-1.3 l0.6-2.2l-0.5-2.5l1.4-2.1l5.8-1.1l-5.5-0.7l-6.6,3.7l-4.1-3.2l-2.2,1l-2.2-1.2l-0.5-4.9l0.9-2.5l3-0.5l-0.9-2.2l-0.18-0.31 l13.18-3.89l0.4-6l5.2-3.4l13.2-0.4l1.6-2.9l9-3.9l6.8,3.6l7.2,13.3l-2.7-0.4l-1.9,2.4l8.5,3.3l0.3,5.9l-14.3,2.1l-2.9,2.2l3,0.8 l3.6,4.7l0.8,2.8l-2.8,4.5l2.8,1.4l0.4,3l-4.8-3.5l-1.5,2.4l-3.2,0.7l0.5,3l-2.4,2.1l-2.3-1.7v-3.1l-3.4,0.2l-0.2,9.5l-11.7-5 L213.1,265.2z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Maine-et-Loire" data-numerodepartement="49" class="region-52 departement departement-49 departement-maine-et-loire" d="m270.6,269.2l-12.3,0.8l-10.6-3.8l-0.4-3 l-2.8-1.4l2.8-4.5l-0.8-2.8l-3.6-4.7l-3-0.8l2.9-2.2l14.3-2.1l-0.3-5.9l-8.5-3.3l1.9-2.4l2.7,0.4l-7.2-13.3l0.4-2.2l10.5,3.5 l2.1-1.9l8.7,3.6l3,0.4l5.9-2.7l5.1,1.7l0.6,2.7l6.7-0.2l0.2,3.5l2,2l3.1-1.3l5.2,3.3l7.4,0.1l-0.7,2.4l-1.7,9.3l-5.8,15.3v0.1 l-6.6,5.9l-2.3-2.3l-9.6,0.2l-5.6,0.8L270.6,269.2z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Mayenne" data-numerodepartement="53" class="region-52 departement departement-53 departement-mayenne" d="m256.6,221.5l-10.5-3.5l3.6-8.6l5.5-2.2 l-1.9-17.3l1.5-2.4l0.1-12.1l8.6,0.8h0.1l3.3,3.7l2.4-1.6l2.5,1.7l6.7-3.3h9.1l0.7-2.7l2.7,0.2l1.9,6l3.3,1.6v2.9v0.1l-4.3,2.7 l0.3,6.9l-4.4,4l1.2,2.9l-5,4.6l1.4,3.4l-5.5,7.7l1.5,5.6l-5.1-1.7l-5.9,2.7l-3-0.4l-8.7-3.6L256.6,221.5z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Sarthe" data-numerodepartement="72" class="region-52 departement departement-72 departement-sarthe" d="m312.7,235.3l-6.1-2.6l-7.4-0.1l-5.2-3.3 l-3.1,1.3l-2-2l-0.2-3.5l-6.7,0.2l-0.6-2.7l-1.5-5.6l5.5-7.7l-1.4-3.4l5-4.6l-1.2-2.9l4.4-4l-0.3-6.9l4.3-2.7l3,0.1l11-5.9l2.8,1.5 l1.6,8.4l7.2,5l2.9-1l3.1,3.5l3.2,0.7l2.1,3.8l-0.4,1.8v0.1l-2,2.1l1.7,2.2l0.4,5.5l-6.3,10.6l-3.2,1.1l-0.6,3.5l-7.7,4.5l-2.8-0.3 L312.7,235.3z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Vendée" data-numerodepartement="85" class="region-52 departement departement-85 departement-vendee" d="m269.3,305.1l0.2-7.4l-4.7-17.9l-4.2-4.1l-2.3-5.7l-10.6-3.8l-4.8-3.5l-1.5,2.4l-3.2,0.7 l0.5,3l-2.4,2.1l-2.3-1.7v-3.1l-3.4,0.2l-0.2,9.5l-11.7-5l-5.6-5.6l-0.3,0.1l-0.8,2.6l-3.4,4.3l-1.2,2.3l0.2,2.4l8.7,9.5l2.7,5.6 l1.2,5.3l8,5.4l3.4,0.5l3.9,4.3l2.9-0.1l2,1.2l1.8,2.5l-0.9-2.1l3.9,3.3l0.5-2.7l2.4,0.3l7.1-2.7l-1.4,2.9l6.5-0.3l2.4,1.8l9.1-4.5 L269.3,305.1z"></path>
                    <path data-nom="Côtes-d’Armor" data-numerodepartement="22" class="region-53 departement departement-22 departement-cotes-darmor" d="m208.7,188.9l-4.9,7.1l-2.9,1.1l-1.5-2.7 l-3.5-0.9l-6.2,7.5l-1.8-6l-3,0.9l-12.9-6.5l-7.9,3l-12.46-3.29l2.06-4.11l-2.5-9.3l2.5-8.3l-3.6-4.7l1.1-4.3l1.2,1.4l3.2-0.4 l1.1-7.7l1.5-1.6l2.2-0.6l1.9,1.4h2.5l2.1-1l2.2,0.3l1.5-1.8l0.9,2L170,153l3-3.6l2.9-0.8l-0.1,2.3l-1.2,4.4l1.7-3.1l2.6-0.5l-1.1,2 l7.2,7.8l2.2,5.4l3,2l0.8,3.7l0.7-2.2l3-1l2.4-2.7l8.1-3.3l2.7-0.2l-2,2.5l2.9-1.1l1.8,4.4l1.3-1.9l2.5,0.2v-0.09l1.6,3.99h-0.3h0.3 l2.5,0.3l0.7,0.2l0.4,1.7l-1.9,13L208.7,188.9z"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Please add javascript, html, original svg image in question.

Comment: I added the svg

Comment: let me check. bro :)

Comment: Is used any css code. the svg shows nothing .should be blank

Comment: I go it you have not add color i  `fill="none"` makes blank changes to any color fill="#ccc"

Comment: @ClémentPageaux, now you have more than 15 points and you could vote. If you are satisfied with my answer below, please do not forget to upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `data-name` attribute you could use `title` element inside `path` elements. It works like `title` attribute in HTML (but `title` attribute does not work on SVG elements). I have moved your `data-name` attribute values into `title` elements inside `path`.

Also you do not need to use 53 event listeners (1 for each `path` element). You can use only one event listener for all this paths.

For emulation of modal dialog we use `rect` element with center position. It is half modal because you can see tooltips from `title` elements.

### Demo

**How to see it:** you have to resize the snippet view to "Full page" (on the top right of the snippet view you will find this possibility) or you have to scroll the snippet view to see the modal rect.

```js
var activePath;
document.querySelector('#map').addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    var t = e.target;
    if(document.querySelector('.modal').style.display != 'block')
    {
        if(t.tagName == 'path')
        {
            activePath = t;
            t.classList.add('active');
            
            var modalTxt = document.querySelector('#modal-txt');
            modalTxt.innerHTML = 'Departement: ' + t.firstChild.innerHTML;
            modalTxt.nextSibling.innerHTML = 'Departement-number: ' + t.getAttribute('data-numerodepartement');
            modalTxt.parentNode.style.display='block';
        }
    }
    else if(t.parentNode.classList.contains('modal'))
    {
        activePath.classList.remove('active');
        t.parentNode.style.display='none';
    }
});
```

```css
path{fill:#6bf}
path.active{fill:#49d}
.modal{display:none}
```

```html
<svg id="map" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 667 578" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
        <g id="france" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(0.000000, 1.000000)">
            <g id="complete_map" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup">
                <path id="div1" data-numerodepartement="971" class="region-01 departement departement-971 departement-guadeloupe" d="M35.87,487.13l0.7,7.2l-4.5-1.1l-2,1.7l-5.8-0.6l-1.7-1.2l4.9,0.5l3.2-4.4L35.87,487.13z M104.87,553.63 l-4.4-1.8l-1.9,0.8l0.2,2.1l-1.9,0.3l-2.2,4.9l0.7,2.4l1.7,2.9l3.4,1.2l3.4-0.5l5.3-5l-0.4-2.5L104.87,553.63z M110.27,525.53 l-6.7-2.2l-2.4-4.2l-11.1-2.5l-2.7-5.7l-0.7-7.7l-6.2-4.7l-5.9,5.5l-0.8,2.9l1.2,4.5l3.1,1.2l-1,3.4l-2.6,1.2l-2.5,5.1l-1.9-0.2 l-1,1.9l-4.3-0.7l1.8-0.7l-3.5-3.7l-10.4-4.1l-3.4,1.6l-2.4,4.8l-0.5,3.5l3.1,9.7l0.6,12l6.3,9l0.6,2.7c3-1.2,6-2.5,9.1-3.7l5.9-6.9 l-0.4-8.7l-2.8-5.3l0.2-5.5l3.6,0.2l0.9-1.7l1.4,3.1l6.8,2l13.8-4.9L110.27,525.53z"><title>Guadeloupe</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="972" class="region-02 departement departement-972 departement-martinique" d="m44.23,433.5l1.4-4.1l-6.2-7.5l0.3-5.8l4.8-4 l4.9-0.9l17,9.9l7,8.8l9.4-5.2l1.8,2.2l-2.8,0.8l0.7,2.6l-2.9,1l-2.2-2.4l-1.9,1.7l0.6,2.5l5.1,1.6l-5.3,4.9l1.6,2.3l4.5-1.5 l-0.8,5.6l3.7,0.2l7.6,19l-1.8,5.5l-4.1,5.1h-2.6l-2-3l3.7-5.7l-4.3,1.7l-2.5-2.5l-2.4,1.2l-6-2.8l-5.5,0.1l-5.4,3.5l-2.4-2.1 l0.2-2.7l-2-2l2.5-4.9l3.4-2.5l4.9,3.4l3.2-1.9l-4.4-4.7l0.2-2.4l-1.8,1.2l-7.2-1.1l-7.6-7L44.23,433.5z"><title>Martinique</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="973" class="region-03 departement departement-973 departement-guyane" d="m95.2,348.97l-11.7,16.4l0.3,2.4l-7.3,14.9 l-4.4,3.9l-2.6,1.3l-2.3-1.7l-4.4,0.8l0.7-1.8l-10.6-0.3l-4.3,0.8l-4.1,4.1l-9.1-4.4l6.6-11.8l0.3-6l4.2-10.8l-8.3-9.6l-2.7-8 l-0.6-11.4l3.8-7.5l5.9-5.4l1-4l4.2,0.5l-2.3-2l24.7,8.6l9.2,8.8l3.1,0.3l-0.7,1.2l6.1,4l1.4,4.1l-2.4,3.1l2.6-1.6l0.1-5.5l4,3.5 l2.4,7L95.2,348.97z"><title>Guyane</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="974" class="region-04 departement departement-974 departement-la-reunion" d="m41.33,265.3l-6.7-8.5l1.3-6l4.1-2.4l0.7-7.9 l3.3,0.4l7.6-6.1l5.7-0.8l21,4l5,5.3v4.1l7.3,10.1l6.7,4.5l1,3.6l-3.3,7.9l0.9,9.6l-3.4,3.5l-17.3,2.9l-19.6-6.5l-3.8-3.6l-4.7-1.2 l-0.9-2.5l-3.6-2.3L41.33,265.3z"><title>La Réunion</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="976" class="region-06 departement departement-976 departement-mayotte" d="m57.79,157.13l11.32,5.82l-3.24,7.46l-5.66,7.52l5.66,8.37l-4.04,5.7l-5.66,8.01l5.66,4.37l-7.28,4.37l-8.09-2.73l-4.04-5.04v-4.85l-3.24-6.55l7.28,3.88l4.04,1.13v-7.14l-4.85-8.43v-14.8l-8.09-2.61l-3.24-2.67v-5.76l8.9-6.79l7.28,10.19L57.79,157.13z M78.07,164.38l-5.56,3.42l4.81,5.59l3.93-4.79L78.07,164.38z"><title>Mayotte</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="75" class="region-11 departement departement-75 departement-paris" d="M641.8,78.3l-0.2,3.8l-1,2.6l-8.3-1.7l-6-0.6l-5.2,3h-4l-2.5-0.3l-0.4-0.1l-13.5-5l-3-3.8l-4.3-1.9l-0.5-0.2 l0.4-1.9l1.3-3.1l2.7-2.1l2.9-1.1l3.9,0.5h0.1l0.9-2.2l7.1-4.6l14-0.1l1.8,3.6l1.8,2.4l0.6,0.9l0.1,0.4L631,68l0.4,5.4l0.4,1.8v0.1 l-0.3,0.8l0.1,3.6l0.6-0.5l1.6-1.6l2-0.5l2-0.5L641.8,78.3z M396.8,154.7l-3.2-0.5l-2.5,1.7l3,3.5l5.3-0.1l-1.8-1.9L396.8,154.7z"><title>Paris</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="77" class="region-11 departement departement-77 departement-seine-et-marne" d="m441.1,176.1l-2.9,0.8l0.4,8.5l-15.4,3 l-0.2,5.8l-3.9,5.4l-11.2,2.7l-9.2-0.7l2.6-1.5l0.6-2.7l-4.2-4.3L397,190l3.4-4.8l4-17.2l-0.5-1l1.1-4.1l-0.3-2.9v-0.1l-1.3-4.7 l1.3-2.5l-1.7-5.1l0.1-0.1l1.7-2.3l-0.2-2l6.9,1l2-2.2l2.5,1.6l8.1-2.9l2.6,0.7l1.8,2.5l-0.7,2.8l3.9,4.2l9.3,6l-0.4,2l-2.6,2.2 l3.5,8.3l2.6,1.7L441.1,176.1z"><title>Seine-et-Marne</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="78" class="region-11 departement departement-78 departement-yvelines" d="m364.1,158.1l-3.6-6.6l-1.8-5.8l2.3-2.6 l3.8,0.1l9.5,0.8l9,3.6l5.5,6.1l-2,3.1l3.2,5.2l-7.1,5.4l-1.6,2.6l0.7,2.9l-4.6,8.6l-3.1,0.7L372,180l-1.2-5.6l-6.2-5.4L364.1,158.1z"><title>Yvelines</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="91" class="region-11 departement departement-91 departement-essonne" d="m401.6,164.8l2.3,2.2l0.5,1l-4,17.2L397,190 l-3.7-0.6l-2.8,1.8l-1.5-2.7l-1.9,2.9l-6.9,0.7l-2.8-10.6l4.6-8.6l-0.7-2.9l1.6-2.6l7.1-5.4v-0.1l3.7,1.6l5.1,2.1L401.6,164.8z"><title>Essonne</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="92" class="region-11 departement departement-92 departement-hauts-de-seine" d="M391.1,155.9l3,3.5l-0.4,4.1l-3.7-1.6v0.1l-3.2-5.2l2-3.1l3.6-2.6l1.3,2l-0.1,1.1L391.1,155.9z M612.6,54.1 l1.6-0.7l0.7-1.9l0.5-1.8l-0.1-1.1l-0.2-1.4l-4.6-1.9l-4.6-0.9l-4,1.3l-7.6,5.6l-6.1,5.8l-5.3,3l-1,1l-3.75,7.4l1.79,7.17 l-0.06,0.07l0.01,0.06l-2.74,3.23l0.68,2.44l2.5,4.8l3.3-0.5l1,5.2l3.9-0.3l1.4,3.5l3.4,1.6l0.5,2.1l5.3,4.2l4.3,1.3l-0.1,4.9 l5.7,3.5l3.15-5.91l-0.7-5.46l0.72-1.2l0.4-1.3l0.7-2.1l-1.4-1.9l0.3-1.2l0.8-2.8l-1-2.6l0.5-0.3l0.5-0.3l0.9-0.5l0.7-1.1l-0.4-0.1 l-13.5-5l-3-3.8l-4.3-1.9l-0.5-0.2l0.3-1.9l1.4-3.1l2.7-2.1l2.8-1.1h0.1l3.9,0.5l0.9-2.2l7.2-4.6l-0.7-2l-0.6-2l1.4-0.7L612.6,54.1z"><title>Hauts-de-Seine</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="93" class="region-11 departement departement-93 departement-seine-saint-denis" d="M404.7,152.7l-1.3,2.5l1.3,4.7v0.1l-7.1-2.6l-0.8-2.7l-3.2-0.5l0.1-1.1l-1.3-2l3.3-1.3l2.6,1.1 c1.6-1.1,3.2-2.2,4.7-3.3L404.7,152.7z M663.2,73.89l0.06-0.08l-0.02-0.04l2.61-3.38l-3.95-0.3l-1.6-5.9l0.06-0.06l-0.02-0.06 l6.36-6.56l0.1-5.42l1.1-4l-1.2-3.4l-5.1-8l0.07-0.08l-0.03-0.04l2.65-3.33l-0.89-4.04l-4.5-2.9l-4.1,1.7l-6.4,8.8l-8.2,6.2 l-0.7-0.2l-7.8-1.1l-1.9,1l-5.1-4.6l-1.3-0.2l-1.9-0.7l-5.1,3l-1.6,2.7l-1-1.2l-5.9-2.1l-1.96,2.25v0.2l0.66,2.45l3.9,0.8l4.7,1.9 l0.1,1.4l0.1,1.1l-0.2,0.9l-0.3,0.9l-0.7,1.9l-1.6,0.7l-0.3,0.8l-1.4,0.7l0.6,2l0.7,2l13.9-0.2l0.1,0.1l1.8,3.6l1.8,2.4l0.6,0.8 l0.1,0.5L631,68l0.4,5.4l0.4,1.8l5.9-0.5l0.5-0.3c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0l6.3-2.8l2.9,0.4l0.7,1.3l3,1.5l4,2.9c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2 l0.7,0.5l6,6.2l0.8,0.6c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1l3.6,2.6l0.04-0.13l0.43-1.3l0.23-0.68l-1.8-6L663.2,73.89z"><title>Seine-Saint-Denis</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="94" class="region-11 departement departement-94 departement-val-de-marne" d="M404.7,160l0.3,2.9l-1.1,4.1l-2.3-2.2l-2.8,0.8l-5.1-2.1l0.4-4.1l5.3-0.1l-1.8-1.9L404.7,160z M668.09,102.2 h0.06l-0.02-0.12l3.31-0.19l-1.55-3.58l-3.69-2.41l0.8-8h-0.1l-3.6-2.6c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1l-0.8-0.6l-6-6.2l-0.7-0.5 c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.2l-4-2.9l-3-1.5l-0.7-1.3l-2.9-0.4l-6.3,2.8c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0l-0.5,0.3l-5.9,0.5v0.1l-0.3,0.8l0.1,3.6 l0.6-0.5l1.6-1.7l2-0.4l2-0.5l4,1.7l-0.2,3.8l-1,2.6l-8.3-1.7l-6-0.6l-5.2,3h-4l-2.5-0.3l-0.6,1.1h-0.1l-0.9,0.5l-0.5,0.3l-0.5,0.3 l1,2.5v0.1l-0.8,2.8l-0.3,1.2l1.4,1.9l-0.7,2.1l-0.4,1.3l-0.7,1.2l0.78,5.38h0.06l2.1,0.2l4.7,2.8l3.1-2.2l0.1,5.5l3.3,2.4l4.9-1.8 l0.7,2.5l5.2-2.3l0.5,1.3l1.7,1.7l4.6-3.6l2.1-0.5l5.2-1.8l1.9,6.8l1.7,2.5l3.3,1.8l5.44,1.88l-0.68-5.05l0.05-0.08l-0.01-0.04 l2.5-4.2l2.73-2.74l-1.38-3.64l0.07-0.06l-0.03-0.07l2.35-1.96L668.09,102.2z"><title>Val-de-Marne</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="95" class="region-11 departement departement-95 departement-val-doise" d="m374.3,144l-9.5-0.8l4-9.5l1.6,3.2l5.6,1.1 l6.3-1.8l9.2,2.2l2.2-1.6l10.9,6.4l0.2,2l-1.7,2.3l-0.1,0.1c-1.5,1.1-3.1,2.2-4.7,3.3l-2.6-1.1l-3.3,1.3l-3.6,2.6l-5.5-6.1 L374.3,144z"><title>Val-d’Oise</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="18" class="region-24 departement departement-18 departement-cher" d="m385.3,235.4l5-2.4l13.5,3.1l3.9,4.8l9-1.7l2,6.5l-1.7,5.8l2.7,2.1 l3.1,7.6l0.3,5.9l2.2,2l-0.2,5.8l-1.3,8.9h-0.1h-4l-4.8,3.7l-8.4,2.9l-2.3,1.9l1.7,5.3l-1.7,2.4l-8.7,1l-3.5,5.9v0.1l-4.9-0.2 l1.5-3.5l-0.9-8.9l-4.7-7.9l1.4-2.7l-2.3-2.2l2.5-5.1l-2.3-11.7l-11.6-1.6l2.8-5.5l2.8,0.1l0.6-2.8l9.7-2l-2.1-5.9l5.9-4.1 L385.3,235.4z"><title>Cher</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="28" class="region-24 departement departement-28 departement-eure-et-loir" d="m333.1,200.9l-2.1-3.8l-1.1-7.5l7.5-5.1 l-0.5-4.6l0.2-4.5l-4.8-4.4l-0.1-3.2l2.4-2.6l6-1.1l5.3-3.2l2.8,1.6l6-1.3l-0.2-2.8l6-6.9l3.6,6.6l0.5,10.9l6.2,5.4l1.2,5.6l2.3,2.2 l3.1-0.7l2.8,10.6l-0.5,1.5l-4.8,10.8l-8.5,0.6l-6,2.8l0.2,2.8l-3.3-1.9l-5.5,3.5L339,201.4l-6.3,1.3L333.1,200.9z"><title>Eure-et-Loir</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="36" class="region-24 departement departement-36 departement-indre" d="m357.8,308.5l-2.8,2.9l-1.7-2.5l-5.8,1.1 l-2.6-1.1l1.5-2.8l-2.5-1.3l-2.6-5.4h-2.9l-4.6-4.4l0.8-5.8l-2.1-3l5.6-0.5l-1-2.7l3.3-11.9l5.1-2.7l2.3,1.7l2.6-3.5l2.5-2.1l-1-4.9 l6-3.2l2.5,1.3l1.5-2.6l6.4-0.9l5.2,3.5l-2.8,5.5l11.6,1.6l2.3,11.7l-2.5,5.1l2.3,2.2l-1.4,2.7l4.7,7.9l0.9,8.9l-1.5,3.5l-2.7,0.8 l-13.2-2.7l-1.9,2.5L357.8,308.5z"><title>Indre</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="37" class="region-24 departement departement-37 departement-indre-et-loire" d="m303.9,263l-5.5-3.2v-0.1l5.8-15.3l1.7-9.3 l0.7-2.4l6.1,2.6l-0.5-3.3l2.8,0.3l7.7-4.5l10.5,0.5l-0.2,5.5l2.2-1.8l6,3.4l-0.7,2.7l3.4,5.1l-1.2,9.1l2.4,1.9l2.6-1.3l4.2,6.7 l1,4.9l-2.5,2.1l-2.6,3.5l-2.3-1.7l-5.1,2.7l-3.3,11.9l1,2.7l-5.6,0.5l-7.1-10l-0.3-3.1l-5.3-3l1.4,2.9l-10,0.4l-2.8-1.4l-1.3-6.1 l-2.9,0.3L303.9,263z"><title>Indre-et-Loire</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="41" class="region-24 departement departement-41 departement-loir-et-cher" d="m357.9,256.4l-6,3.2l-4.2-6.7l-2.6,1.3 l-2.4-1.9l1.2-9.1l-3.4-5.1l0.7-2.7l-6-3.4l-2.2,1.8l0.2-5.5l-10.5-0.5l0.6-3.5l3.2-1.1l6.3-10.6l-0.4-5.5l-1.7-2.2l2-2.1v-0.1 l6.3-1.3l12.8,10.8l5.5-3.5l3.3,1.9l2.5,7.1l-1.8,3.2l1.7,5.6l3-1.3l2.4,1.5l1.1,3.8l2.9,0.6l1.9-2.3l15.2,1.6l0.8,2.6l-5,2.4 l5.1,7.6l-5.9,4.1l2.1,5.9l-9.7,2l-0.6,2.8l-2.8-0.1l-5.2-3.5l-6.4,0.9l-1.5,2.6L357.9,256.4z"><title>Loir-et-Cher</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="45" class="region-24 departement departement-45 departement-loiret" d="m393.3,189.4l3.7,0.6l0.7,3.1l4.2,4.3l-0.6,2.7 l-2.6,1.5l9.2,0.7l11.2-2.7l6.7,7.5l0.4,5.8l-4.6,4.9l1.1,2.9l-1.6,2.4l-5.3,3.3l3,2.8l2.2,6.9l-2.8,0.7l-1.5,2.4l-9,1.7l-3.9-4.8 l-13.5-3.1l-0.8-2.6l-15.2-1.6l-1.9,2.3l-2.9-0.6l-1.1-3.8l-2.4-1.5l-3,1.3l-1.7-5.6l1.8-3.2l-2.5-7.1l-0.2-2.8l6-2.8l8.5-0.6 l4.8-10.8l0.5-1.5l6.9-0.7l1.9-2.9l1.5,2.7L393.3,189.4z"><title>Loiret</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="21" class="region-27 departement departement-21 departement-cote-dor" d="m523.6,241.7l3.9,8.2l-1.2,1.3l-1.8,8.2 l-6.2,6.8l-1.1,4.1v-0.1l-15,1.5l-8.8,4.2l-5.6-6.3l-5.5-1.9l-1.3-2.6l-5.7-1.7l-2.4-2.6V260l0.4-3.2l-3.7-1.2l-1.3-6h0.1l-1.3-2.7 l1.3-8.1l6.7-10.4l-1.7-2.3l2.8-2.1l0.3-3.7l-3.1-3.9l1.9-3.1l2.2-2l6.1-0.9l4.7-3.9l3.9,0.5l3.5,0.7l0.5,2.7l2.6,1l-0.3,2.9 l2.9,0.3l1.8,2.2l1,3.1l-2.8,2.4l2.3,4.8l9.2,2l3,1.6v2.8l4.8-1.9h0.1l2.7-1.6l2,3l0.1,3.2l-4.6,4.1L523.6,241.7z"><title>Côte-d’Or</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="25" class="region-27 departement departement-25 departement-doubs" d="m590.1,245.2l-2.4,2.2l0.4,3l-4.8,6.2l-4.8,4 l-0.4,2.9l-2.5,2.7l-5.7,1.7l-0.3,0.3l-1.7,2.3l0.9,2.7l-0.7,4.5l0.5,2.5l-9.5,8.8l-2.9,5.2l-0.22,0.69l-3.68-3.49l3.6-7.4l2.1-2.3 l-4.2-4.1l-2.9-0.5l-5.8-10.1l-3,0.8l-1.5-2.5l-2,2.1l-1.2-2.5l3-5.1l-5.2-7.8l22.3-10.2l3-4.7l5.6-1.9l2.8,0.9l1.8-2.2l3.2-0.4 l0.5-2.8l5.9,0.8l0.2-0.1h0.1l5.9,2.7l-1.4,2.5l1.4,2.4l0.41-0.46l-0.11,0.16l-2.2,4.9l7-0.7L590.1,245.2z"><title>Doubs</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="39" class="region-27 departement departement-39 departement-jura" d="m552.3,291.4l3.68,3.49L553.4,303l-5.3,7.2 l-5.5,3.2l-3.8,0.2l-0.4-2.8l-3.4-1.6l-4,4.4l-2.9,0.1l-0.1-3h-2.9l-4.3-7.7l2.8-1.1l-0.8-5.3l2.8-5l-2.2-8.7l-2.5-1.6l5-3.7 l-8.3-4.4l-0.4-2.9l1.1-4.1l6.2-6.8l1.8-8.2l1.2-1.3l2.3,2l5.4,0.1l5.2,7.8l-3,5.1l1.2,2.5l2-2.1l1.5,2.5l3-0.8l5.8,10.1l2.9,0.5 l4.2,4.1l-2.1,2.3L552.3,291.4z"><title>Jura</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="58" class="region-27 departement departement-58 departement-nievre" d="m462.8,250l5.5-0.4l1.3,6l3.7,1.2l-0.4,3.2v0.8 l-1.1,0.3l-2.7,0.4v1.3l-2.8,1l0.3,5.9l-2.1,1.7l4,7l-1.9,2.1l0.7,2.9l-11.3,5.7l-7-2.8l-5.9,6l-4.4-3.7l-2.8,1.7l-6.4-0.2l-5.7-6.3 l1.3-8.9l0.2-5.8l-2.2-2l-0.3-5.9l-3.1-7.6l-2.7-2.1l1.7-5.8l-2-6.5l1.5-2.4l2.8-0.7v0.1h3.4l7.4,4.8h6l4.6-4.3l3.9,5.6l5.5,3 l5.8-0.9l0.9,3.7l2.8-0.9L462.8,250z"><title>Nièvre</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="70" class="region-27 departement departement-70 departement-haute-saone" d="m579.1,225.9l1.4,5.5l-0.2,0.1l-5.9-0.8 l-0.5,2.8l-3.2,0.4l-1.8,2.2l-2.8-0.9l-5.6,1.9l-3,4.7L535.2,252l-5.4-0.1l-2.3-2l-3.9-8.2l-2.6-1.4l4.6-4.1l-0.1-3.2l-2-3l-2.7,1.6 h-0.1l1.2-2.5l6.6-3.9l2.1,1.8l3.2-1l0.3-8.3l2-2.4l2.9,0.3l2.3-3.2l-0.2-1.4l8-5.8l7,4.3l5.8-1.6l4.9,3.6l5.1-2.2l8.4,6.6l-2.3,5.7 L579.1,225.9z"><title>Haute-Saône</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="71" class="region-27 departement departement-71 departement-saone-et-loire" d="m517.2,270.2v0.1l0.4,2.9l8.3,4.4l-5,3.7 l2.5,1.6l2.2,8.7l-2.8,5l0.8,5.3l-2.8,1.1l-4.8-3.3l-5.4,1.3l-5.9-1.5l-5.9,20.9l-5.7-7.7l-1.6,2.3l-2.5-1.5l-2.2,1.6l-2.2-1.7 l-2.3,1.9l-0.29,2.91L482,318.2v0.1l-5.7,3.8l-2.1-2.1l-8,1.5l-5.2-3.3v-3l3.7-4.6l0.5-5.5l-1.6-2.4l-7.9-2.9l-6.7-13.5l7,2.8 l11.3-5.7l-0.7-2.9l1.9-2.1l-4-7l2.1-1.7l-0.3-5.9l2.8-1l2.7-1.7l1.1-0.3l2.4,2.6l5.7,1.7l1.3,2.6l5.5,1.9l5.6,6.3l8.8-4.2 L517.2,270.2z"><title>Saône-et-Loire</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="89" class="region-27 departement departement-89 departement-yonne" d="m425.8,207.1l-6.7-7.5l3.9-5.4l0.2-5.8l15.4-3 l3.6,1.5l4.5,5.5l2.5,8.3l2-2.2l3.6,4.1l5,10.9l12.6-1.6l2.9,1.4l-1.9,3.1l3.1,3.9l-0.3,3.7l-2.8,2.1l1.7,2.3l-6.7,10.4l-1.3,8.1 l1.3,2.7h-0.1l-5.5,0.4l-1.5-2.8l-2.8,0.9l-0.9-3.7l-5.8,0.9l-5.5-3l-3.9-5.6l-4.6,4.3h-6l-7.4-4.8H421v-0.1l-2.2-6.9l-3-2.8 l5.3-3.3l1.6-2.4l-1.1-2.9l4.6-4.9L425.8,207.1z"><title>Yonne</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="90" class="region-27 departement departement-90 departement-territoire-de-belfort" d="m580.3,215.9l0.9-0.6l7.6,5l0.5,9l2.8-0.2l2,5 l-0.1,0.1l-2.79,0.39l-1.11-0.39l-3.19,4.34L586.5,239l-1.4-2.4l1.4-2.5l-5.9-2.7h-0.1l-1.4-5.5l-1.1-4.3L580.3,215.9z"><title>Territoire de Belfort</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="14" class="region-28 departement departement-14 departement-calvados" d="m316.9,148l-0.7,2.2l-5.6-1l-7,1.7l-7.2,5.4 l-2.9,0.3l-5.7-1.1l-2.6,1.7l-4.9-3l-6.4,2.3l-2.7-1.3l-0.9,2.7l-5.4,2.9l-9.7-2.1l-1.8-2.4l4.5-5.3l-1.6-2.3l8.1-4.9l-2.2-8.2 l2-2.6l-8.4-3.1l-0.5-6.6v-0.1l0.1-0.7l1.8,0.8l1.9-2.1l3.4-0.3l9.4,3.3l13.9,1.5l6.9,3.4l5.7-0.7l4.7-2.5l4.1-3.7l5.1-1.1l0.3,8.3 h2.9l-2.3,2.1l2.8,9.4l-1.4,3L316.9,148z"><title>Calvados</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="27" class="region-28 departement departement-27 departement-eure" d="m316.4,153.4l-0.2-3.2l0.7-2.2l-2.3-4.1l1.4-3l-2.8-9.4l2.3-2.1h-2.9 l-0.3-8.3l1.7-0.4l0.28-0.1h1.52l-0.9-0.2l0.8-0.3l-1.29-0.3l5.89-2.4l7.6,5l3.4-0.7l4.9,3l-1.9,2.4l2.1,2.1l5.4,2.4l1.4-2.7 l8.2-2.5l4.8-7l13.1,3.3l3.5,8.4l-4,2.6l-4,9.5l-3.8-0.1l-2.3,2.6l1.8,5.8l-6,6.9l0.2,2.8l-6,1.3l-2.8-1.6l-5.3,3.2l-6,1.1l-2.4,2.6 l-3.4-2.1l1.7-2.3l-7.8-9.5L316.4,153.4z"><title>Eure</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="50" class="region-28 departement departement-50 departement-manche" d="m255.2,158.7l9.7,2.1l4.1,4.2l-1.8,6.7 l-3.6,4.5h-0.1l-8.6-0.8l-5.4-2.3l-7.1,4.8l-2.7-1l-4.7-9.6l1.9-0.2l4.8,0.4l2.5-1.1l0.5-2.2l-2.4,1.3l-5.1-5.6l-0.3-5.3l2-6.1 l-0.3-4.9l-1.8-3.6l0.4-7.4l1.5-2l-2.5,0.3l-2-5l0.3-2.2l-2.4-1.2l-2.9-4.1l-0.7-5.9l-1.4-1.9l1.8-1.8l0.1-2.8l-0.5-2.3l-2.2-1.1 l-1-2.5l2.1-0.2l11.9,4.2h2.4l4-2.6l5.1,0.6l1.8,1.7l0.9,2.7l-3.2,5.2l4,6.5l1.1,4.3l-0.1,0.7v0.1l0.5,6.6l8.4,3.1l-2,2.6l2.2,8.2 l-8.1,4.9l1.6,2.3l-4.5,5.3L255.2,158.7z"><title>Manche</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="61" class="region-28 departement departement-61 departement-orne" d="m266.9,179.9l-3.3-3.7l3.6-4.5l1.8-6.7 l-4.1-4.2l5.4-2.9l0.9-2.7l2.7,1.3l6.4-2.3l4.9,3l2.6-1.7l5.7,1.1l2.9-0.3l7.2-5.4l7-1.7l5.6,1l0.2,3.2l6.3,0.5l7.8,9.5l-1.7,2.3 l3.4,2.1l0.1,3.2l4.8,4.4l-0.2,4.5l0.5,4.6l-7.5,5.1l1.1,7.5l-3.2-0.7l-3.1-3.5l-2.9,1l-7.2-5l-1.6-8.4l-2.8-1.5l-11,5.9l-3-0.1 v-0.1v-2.9l-3.3-1.6l-1.9-6l-2.7-0.2l-0.7,2.7h-9.1l-6.7,3.3l-2.5-1.7L266.9,179.9z"><title>Orne</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="76" class="region-28 departement departement-76 departement-seine-maritime" d="m314.41,119.8l-7.61-1.8l-1.2-2l-0.1-2.3 l4.4-9.7l13.8-7.4L326,95l10.3-2.1l4.8-1.8l2.4,0.3L352,87l5.11-4.09l11.79,9.99l3.4,8.4l-3.1,4.7l1.4,8.7l-1.3,8l-13.1-3.3l-4.8,7 l-8.2,2.5l-1.4,2.7l-5.4-2.4l-2.1-2.1l1.9-2.4l-4.9-3l-3.4,0.7l-7.6-5L314.41,119.8z"><title>Seine-Maritime</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="02" class="region-32 departement departement-02 departement-aisne" d="m450.3,82.6l16.7,4.6l2.91,0.94L470.6,94l-1.3,3.5l1.3,3.1l-5,7.2 l-2.7,0.3l0.3,14.3l-1,2.8l-5.3-1.8l-8,4l-1.2,2.6l3.2,8l-5.5,2.3l1.6,2.4l-0.8,2.7l2.5,1.3l-7.7,10.2l-9.3-6l-3.9-4.2l0.7-2.8 l-1.8-2.5l-2.6-0.7l2.1-1.7l-0.5-2.8l-2.9-1.1l-2.4,1.5l-0.7-2.9l3,0.2l-2.9-4.5l2.6-1.7l2.4-5.7l2.6-1.1l-2.2-1.8l0.8-4.5 l-0.4-10.2l-2.3-7l3.9-8.1l0.4-3.8l12.6-0.6l2.6-2.2l2.3,1.7L450.3,82.6z"><title>Aisne</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="59" class="region-32 departement departement-59 departement-nord" d="m384.33,25.06l0.87-0.26l2,0.8l1.1-2.1l7.9-2.1 l2.9,0.3l4.4-1.9v-0.1l1.2,4.8l2.3,3.7l-1.6,1.9l0.6,0.8l1.2,5.8h3.4l2.7,5.1l3.1,1.5h2.1l0.6-2.4l8.1-3l3.8,7.5l0.1,1l1.3,5.2 l2,3.5h0.1l2.8,0.6l2.1-1.4l2.4-0.2l-0.5,2.2l2.2-0.7l2.8,1l1.8,4.4l-0.6,2.3l0.7,2.3l1.4,1.9l1.1-2.6l4.6-0.3l2.4,1.1L462,64l5.5,6 l2.3,0.2l-2.1,2.4l-1.4,4.7l2.6,0.2l1.4,3.3l-3.5,3.9l0.2,2.5l-16.7-4.6l-5.2,1.8l-2.3-1.7l-2.6,2.2l-12.6,0.6l-3.3-2.6l3.5-10.6 l-1.8-2.4l-3-0.4l0.7-2.7l-3.9-5.2l3.1-1.6l-3.8-5.3l-5.9-1l1-6.1l-1.3-2.5l-1.7,2.2l-11.6-0.5l-4.1-4.2l0.6-2.8l-5.5-2.6 L384.33,25.06z"><title>Nord</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="60" class="region-32 departement departement-60 departement-oise" d="m372.8,131.1l-3.5-8.4l1.3-8l-1.4-8.7l3.1-4.7 l4.1,3.7l3.1-1.2l14.4,2.2l12.8,6.7l8.6-6.8l10.3-1.5l0.4,10.2l-0.8,4.5l2.2,1.8l-2.6,1.1l-2.4,5.7l-2.6,1.7l2.9,4.5l-3-0.2l0.7,2.9 l2.4-1.5l2.9,1.1l0.5,2.8l-2.1,1.7l-8.1,2.9l-2.5-1.6l-2,2.2l-6.9-1l-10.9-6.4l-2.2,1.6l-9.2-2.2L376,138l-5.6-1.1l-1.6-3.2 L372.8,131.1z"><title>Oise</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="62" class="region-32 departement departement-62 departement-pas-de-calais" d="m379.8,68.9l7.1,5.8l12-2.5l-2.6,5.7L398,81 l2.5-3.1l8.4,3.5l0.8-2.8l2.8,4.6l2.4-1.7l0.8,3.2l8.6-1.8l3.5-10.6l-1.8-2.4l-3-0.4l0.7-2.7l-3.9-5.2l3.1-1.6l-3.8-5.3l-5.9-1 l1-6.1l-1.3-2.5l-1.7,2.2l-11.6-0.5l-4.1-4.2l0.6-2.8l-5.5-2.6l-6.27-12.14L372.6,28.5l-6.4,5.4l0.9,5.6l-1.7,4.6l0.6,6.7l2,4.2 l-1.7-1.4l-0.3,9.7l2.27,1.58l10.53,1.02L379.8,68.9z"><title>Pas-de-Calais</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="80" class="region-32 departement departement-80 departement-somme" d="m424.3,82.9l3.3,2.6l-0.4,3.8l-3.9,8.1l2.3,7 l-10.3,1.5l-8.6,6.8l-12.8-6.7l-14.4-2.2l-3.1,1.2l-4.1-3.7l-3.4-8.4l-11.79-9.99L359.5,81l3.4-6.6l1.9-1.1l0.1-0.1l1.4,1.8l3.5,0.3 l-5.6-6l1.2-5.1l2.9,0.7l-0.03-0.02l10.53,1.02l1,3l7.1,5.8l12-2.5l-2.6,5.7L398,81l2.5-3.1l8.4,3.5l0.8-2.8l2.8,4.6l2.4-1.7 l0.8,3.2L424.3,82.9z"><title>Somme</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="08" class="region-44 departement departement-08 departement-ardennes" d="m469.91,88.14l0.79,0.26l9.8,0.4l7.3-3.2l1.1-6 l4-3.8l2.8-0.2v3.8L494,81l-0.6,5.2l3.3,4.5l-1,2.4l0.6,3.1l1.4,1.9l3.3-0.9l4.3,2.4l2.8,3.8l4.9,0.6l2,1.7l-0.9,2.4l2.1-0.13 l-1.6,1.13l-2,2.7l-5.7-2.1l-1.9,2l0.8,8.8l-3.2,5.1l1.4,2.5l-4.2,3.6v0.1l-20.1-1.9l-9.8-6.6l-6.7-0.9l-0.3-14.3l2.7-0.3l5-7.2 l-1.3-3.1l1.3-3.5L469.91,88.14z"><title>Ardennes</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="10" class="region-44 departement departement-10 departement-aube" d="m442.2,186.9l-3.6-1.5l-0.4-8.5l2.9-0.8l3-5 l3.2,4.5l9,1.2v-3.3l9.5-7.6l6.5-0.9l3.1,0.5l0.4,6.1l2.6,2c1.9,0.8,3.8,1.5,5.6,2.3l2.5-1.5l3.3,1.1l-0.6,3.4l2.4,5.2l5.6,3 l0.5,9.9l-0.1,2.7l-5.6,2.5l0.2,4.8l-3.9-0.5l-4.7,3.9l-6.1,0.9l-2.2,2l-2.9-1.4l-12.6,1.6l-5-10.9l-3.6-4.1l-2,2.2l-2.5-8.3 L442.2,186.9z"><title>Aube</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="51" class="region-44 departement departement-51 departement-marne" d="m440.6,158.9l0.4-2l7.7-10.2l-2.5-1.3l0.8-2.7 l-1.6-2.4l5.5-2.3l-3.2-8l1.2-2.6l8-4l5.3,1.8l1-2.8l6.7,0.9l9.8,6.6l20.1,1.9l2.2,9l-1,4.1l2.6,1.3l-0.6,3.9l-3.1,1.1l-1.1,5.8 l3.2,4.6l0.5,4.1l-8.6,2.2l2.2,2.5l-2.3,2.2l0.7,2.9h-4.7l-3.3-1.1l-2.5,1.5c-1.8-0.8-3.7-1.5-5.6-2.3l-2.6-2l-0.4-6.1l-3.1-0.5 l-6.5,0.9l-9.5,7.6v3.3l-9-1.2l-3.2-4.5l-2.6-1.7l-3.5-8.3L440.6,158.9z"><title>Marne</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="52" class="region-44 departement departement-52 departement-haute-marne" d="m493.9,167.9l8.6-2.2l3.4,5.2l16.9,10.4 l-2.4,2.3l12.7,9.5l-1.7,8.6l5.5,4.7l0.2,3.1l2.7-1.1l1.3,2.5v0.1l0.2,1.4l-2.3,3.2l-2.9-0.3l-2,2.4l-0.3,8.3l-3.2,1l-2.1-1.8 l-6.6,3.9l-1.2,2.5l-4.8,1.9v-2.8l-3-1.6l-9.2-2l-2.3-4.8l2.8-2.4l-1-3.1l-1.8-2.2l-2.9-0.3l0.3-2.9l-2.6-1l-0.5-2.7l-3.5-0.7 l-0.2-4.8l5.6-2.5l0.1-2.7l-0.5-9.9l-5.6-3l-2.4-5.2l0.6-3.4h4.7l-0.7-2.9l2.3-2.2L493.9,167.9z"><title>Haute-Marne</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="54" class="region-44 departement departement-54 departement-meurthe-et-moselle" d="m588.2,170.9l1.9,1.3l-1.5,0.4l-10.6,7.6l-6.1-1.6l-1.6-2.7l-5.3,3.8 l-6,1l-2.4-1.8l-5.4,2l-1.1,2.8l-5.7,0.7l-4.1-4.8l0.1-2.9l-5.8-0.6l0.2-2.9l-2.5-2l1.7-2.8l-1.3-8.6l2.2-13.8l0.9-2.7l-4.9-11.5 l1.5-5.9l-1.2-2.7l-4.4-4.8l-5.3,2l-0.7-5.3l4.8-1.7l2-1.9h6.8l2.54,2.31L539.6,124l2.5,1.6l1.2,3.6l-1.7,3.1l1,5.6l-2.8,0.1 l4.3,7.5l11.5,4l-0.3,2.9l2.7,5.1l8.5,1.5l5.3,3.9l14.4,5.3L588.2,170.9z"><title>Meurthe-et-Moselle</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="55" class="region-44 departement departement-55 departement-meuse" d="m516.2,107.97l1.2-0.07l1.5,1.6l1.9,5.6 l0.7,5.3l5.3-2l4.4,4.8l1.2,2.7l-1.5,5.9l4.9,11.5l-0.9,2.7l-2.2,13.8l1.3,8.6l-1.7,2.8l2.5,2l-0.2,2.9l-1.9,2.3l-3-0.5l-6.9,3.4 l-16.9-10.4l-3.4-5.2l-0.5-4.1l-3.2-4.6l1.1-5.8l3.1-1.1l0.6-3.9l-2.6-1.3l1-4.1l-2.2-9v-0.1l4.2-3.6l-1.4-2.5l3.2-5.1l-0.8-8.8 l1.9-2l5.7,2.1l2-2.7L516.2,107.97z"><title>Meuse</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="57" class="region-44 departement departement-57 departement-moselle" d="m539.6,124l-2.65-10.19l0.65,0.59h2.4l1.5,2.1 l2.3,0.7l2.3-0.5l1-2.3l2-1.2l2.2-0.2l4.5,2.3l4.9-0.1l3.1,3.8l2.3,1.9l-0.5,2l3.7,3.2l2.8,4.5v2.3l4.2,0.7l1.2-1.9l-0.3-2.4 l2.6-0.2l3.8,1.8l1.4,3.5l2.1-1.5l2.5,1.9l5.8-0.4l5.3-4.2l2.2,1.4l0.5,2.1l2.4,2.4l3.2,1.5h0.03l-1.73,4.4l-1.4,2.6l-8.9,0.3 l-9.1-4.6l-0.8-2.8l-5,10.8l5.5,2.4l-1.6,2.5l2.3,1.7l1.3-2.5l3,0.3l4.3,3.4l-3,13.3l-2.3,1.8l-3.4-0.3l-2-2.7l-14.4-5.3l-5.3-3.9 l-8.5-1.5l-2.7-5.1l0.3-2.9l-11.5-4l-4.3-7.5l2.8-0.1l-1-5.6l1.7-3.1l-1.2-3.6L539.6,124z"><title>Moselle</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="67" class="region-44 departement departement-67 departement-bas-rhin" d="m631.8,140.7l-2.8,9.4l-7.8,10.5l-2,1.5l-1.4,3.3l0.3,4.9l-2.4,7.2 l0.7,3.6l-1.5,2l-1.2,5.5l-3.16,6.23L605.9,193l-0.3-2.8l-8.5-5.6l-3.1-0.2l-5.2-2.2l1.3-10l-1.9-1.3l3.4,0.3l2.3-1.8l3-13.3 l-4.3-3.4l-3-0.3l-1.3,2.5l-2.3-1.7l1.6-2.5l-5.5-2.4l5-10.8l0.8,2.8l9.1,4.6l8.9-0.3l1.4-2.6l1.73-4.4l8.87,0.6l2.4-0.6 L631.8,140.7z"><title>Bas-Rhin</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="68" class="region-44 departement departement-68 departement-haut-rhin" d="m605.9,193l4.64,1.83l-0.04,0.07v5.3l1.6,1.9 l0.2,3.4l-2.2,11.1l0.1,6.7l1.8,1.5l0.6,3.5l-2.2,2l-0.2,2.3l-3.1,0.9l0.5,2.2l-1.5,1.6h-2.7l-3.8,1.4l-3-1.1l0.3-2.5l-2.4-1.1 l-0.4,0.1l-2-5l-2.8,0.2l-0.5-9l-7.6-5l2.8-2.4v-6.2l4.8-7.8l4.1-13.5l1.1-1l3.1,0.2l8.5,5.6L605.9,193z"><title>Haut-Rhin</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="88" class="region-44 departement departement-88 departement-vosges" d="m520.4,183.6l2.4-2.3l6.9-3.4l3,0.5l1.9-2.3 l5.8,0.6l-0.1,2.9l4.1,4.8l5.7-0.7l1.1-2.8l5.4-2l2.4,1.8l6-1l5.3-3.8l1.6,2.7l6.1,1.6l10.6-7.6l1.5-0.4l-1.3,10l5.2,2.2l-1.1,1 l-4.1,13.5l-4.8,7.8v6.2l-2.8,2.4l-0.9,0.6l-8.4-6.6l-5.1,2.2l-4.9-3.6l-5.8,1.6l-7-4.3l-8,5.8v-0.1l-1.3-2.5l-2.7,1.1l-0.2-3.1 l-5.5-4.7l1.7-8.6L520.4,183.6z"><title>Vosges</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="44" class="region-52 departement departement-44 departement-loire-atlantique" d="m213.1,265.2l1.8-1l-2.8-4.1l-7.8-3l3-1.3 l0.6-2.2l-0.5-2.5l1.4-2.1l5.8-1.1l-5.5-0.7l-6.6,3.7l-4.1-3.2l-2.2,1l-2.2-1.2l-0.5-4.9l0.9-2.5l3-0.5l-0.9-2.2l-0.18-0.31 l13.18-3.89l0.4-6l5.2-3.4l13.2-0.4l1.6-2.9l9-3.9l6.8,3.6l7.2,13.3l-2.7-0.4l-1.9,2.4l8.5,3.3l0.3,5.9l-14.3,2.1l-2.9,2.2l3,0.8 l3.6,4.7l0.8,2.8l-2.8,4.5l2.8,1.4l0.4,3l-4.8-3.5l-1.5,2.4l-3.2,0.7l0.5,3l-2.4,2.1l-2.3-1.7v-3.1l-3.4,0.2l-0.2,9.5l-11.7-5 L213.1,265.2z"><title>Loire-Atlantique</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="49" class="region-52 departement departement-49 departement-maine-et-loire" d="m270.6,269.2l-12.3,0.8l-10.6-3.8l-0.4-3 l-2.8-1.4l2.8-4.5l-0.8-2.8l-3.6-4.7l-3-0.8l2.9-2.2l14.3-2.1l-0.3-5.9l-8.5-3.3l1.9-2.4l2.7,0.4l-7.2-13.3l0.4-2.2l10.5,3.5 l2.1-1.9l8.7,3.6l3,0.4l5.9-2.7l5.1,1.7l0.6,2.7l6.7-0.2l0.2,3.5l2,2l3.1-1.3l5.2,3.3l7.4,0.1l-0.7,2.4l-1.7,9.3l-5.8,15.3v0.1 l-6.6,5.9l-2.3-2.3l-9.6,0.2l-5.6,0.8L270.6,269.2z"><title>Maine-et-Loire</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="53" class="region-52 departement departement-53 departement-mayenne" d="m256.6,221.5l-10.5-3.5l3.6-8.6l5.5-2.2 l-1.9-17.3l1.5-2.4l0.1-12.1l8.6,0.8h0.1l3.3,3.7l2.4-1.6l2.5,1.7l6.7-3.3h9.1l0.7-2.7l2.7,0.2l1.9,6l3.3,1.6v2.9v0.1l-4.3,2.7 l0.3,6.9l-4.4,4l1.2,2.9l-5,4.6l1.4,3.4l-5.5,7.7l1.5,5.6l-5.1-1.7l-5.9,2.7l-3-0.4l-8.7-3.6L256.6,221.5z"><title>Mayenne</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="72" class="region-52 departement departement-72 departement-sarthe" d="m312.7,235.3l-6.1-2.6l-7.4-0.1l-5.2-3.3 l-3.1,1.3l-2-2l-0.2-3.5l-6.7,0.2l-0.6-2.7l-1.5-5.6l5.5-7.7l-1.4-3.4l5-4.6l-1.2-2.9l4.4-4l-0.3-6.9l4.3-2.7l3,0.1l11-5.9l2.8,1.5 l1.6,8.4l7.2,5l2.9-1l3.1,3.5l3.2,0.7l2.1,3.8l-0.4,1.8v0.1l-2,2.1l1.7,2.2l0.4,5.5l-6.3,10.6l-3.2,1.1l-0.6,3.5l-7.7,4.5l-2.8-0.3 L312.7,235.3z"><title>Sarthe</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="85" class="region-52 departement departement-85 departement-vendee" d="m269.3,305.1l0.2-7.4l-4.7-17.9l-4.2-4.1l-2.3-5.7l-10.6-3.8l-4.8-3.5l-1.5,2.4l-3.2,0.7 l0.5,3l-2.4,2.1l-2.3-1.7v-3.1l-3.4,0.2l-0.2,9.5l-11.7-5l-5.6-5.6l-0.3,0.1l-0.8,2.6l-3.4,4.3l-1.2,2.3l0.2,2.4l8.7,9.5l2.7,5.6 l1.2,5.3l8,5.4l3.4,0.5l3.9,4.3l2.9-0.1l2,1.2l1.8,2.5l-0.9-2.1l3.9,3.3l0.5-2.7l2.4,0.3l7.1-2.7l-1.4,2.9l6.5-0.3l2.4,1.8l9.1-4.5 L269.3,305.1z"><title>Vendée</title></path>
                <path data-numerodepartement="22" class="region-53 departement departement-22 departement-cotes-darmor" d="m208.7,188.9l-4.9,7.1l-2.9,1.1l-1.5-2.7 l-3.5-0.9l-6.2,7.5l-1.8-6l-3,0.9l-12.9-6.5l-7.9,3l-12.46-3.29l2.06-4.11l-2.5-9.3l2.5-8.3l-3.6-4.7l1.1-4.3l1.2,1.4l3.2-0.4 l1.1-7.7l1.5-1.6l2.2-0.6l1.9,1.4h2.5l2.1-1l2.2,0.3l1.5-1.8l0.9,2L170,153l3-3.6l2.9-0.8l-0.1,2.3l-1.2,4.4l1.7-3.1l2.6-0.5l-1.1,2 l7.2,7.8l2.2,5.4l3,2l0.8,3.7l0.7-2.2l3-1l2.4-2.7l8.1-3.3l2.7-0.2l-2,2.5l2.9-1.1l1.8,4.4l1.3-1.9l2.5,0.2v-0.09l1.6,3.99h-0.3h0.3 l2.5,0.3l0.7,0.2l0.4,1.7l-1.9,13L208.7,188.9z"><title>Côtes-d’Armor</title></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>

    <g class="modal"><rect x="25%" y="40%" width="50%" height="20%" rx="9"  ry="9" fill="black"/><text x="30%" y="47%" fill="#fff" id="modal-txt"></text><text x="30%" y="53%" fill="#fff"></text><text x="71%" y="45%" fill="#fff">&times;</text></g>
</svg>
```

### Second solution with tooltip

It is my [**first answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63477658/1) version with simple tooltip but now with department and it's number. And now I create the tooltip with JS and copy this infos into it.

### [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/bharata/pen/rNeMGRb)

Comment: @ClémentPageaux, if you really needs some modals, then write me more details and I will add it. I do not have it now because I do not know how it should look like and why do you need it.

Comment: Thank you, 
but I'm looking for that when we click on a department a modal with dpt and dpt-number appears. How to do this ?

Comment: @ClémentPageaux, I have added the modal element.

Comment: @ClémentPageaux, or maybe you want it like in my [**first version**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63477658/1) in tooltip but with `dpt` and `dpt-number`?

Answer (score 0):

I added `active` class to clicked `path`. It can be highlight given color by `fill` property.

**JS**

---

```
  paths[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
     _removeClass();
     this.classList.add("active");
  })

  // remove all path active class
  
  function _removeClass(){
       for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
           paths[i].classList.remove('active')
       }
  }
```

**CSS**

---

```
  path.active,path:hover{
      fill: #9fd5f1;
  }
```

**Bootsrap Tooltip** used to show the data-name of each path.

```
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

To set attribute of tooltip

```
  var data_name = paths[i].getAttribute("data-nom");
  paths[i].setAttribute("data-toggle","tooltip");
  paths[i].setAttribute("data-placement","top");
  paths[i].setAttribute("title",data_name);
```

*Bootstrap Tooltip* : Visit https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp

**Working Demo**

---

Codepen : https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/zYqBVRB

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Rayeesac/2htkvxwc/

Comment: @Clément Pageaux check the answer. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/zYqBVRB  are you show this demo.. Now changed with dept number.

Comment: Thank you, you are the best :)

Comment: Are you get the expected output from this .

Comment: Just a last question, I have a problem on the display position of the bubble when it passes over the Ile de France?

Comment: where what is it's dept number ?

Comment: I do not really understand why you load bootstrap.min.css(156 kb.), bootstrap.min.js(58 kb.), jquery.min.js(87 kb.), popper.min.js(20 kb.) = **all 323 kb. only to show some tooltip?!** I can not imagine what you do if you write some big project! You have to think about that each client has to get this 323 kb., each server has to give this 323 kb., each client browser has tausends of objects in memory. And all this has to use a lot of electricity and it implies a lot of earth and air pollution in India and everywhere. Also for server traffic the developer has to pay. It it incredible!

Comment: I used `bootstrap tooltip` to highlight this. Iam not really think about this . i will updated the answer soon. btw thanks :)

Comment: what would you use instead of bootstrap for the tooltip in order to be lighter?

Comment: for dept 75,92,93,94 in the codepen there is a problem on the display position of the bubble when it passes over

Comment: 75,92,93,94 please inspect the path this path containing long. https://i.stack.imgur.com/keGIU.png check from this image.

Comment: @Clément Pageaux are you using bootstrap already in your project?

Comment: **CSS Tootips** used to minimize the *Bootstrap Tooltip*  : visit https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: @Bharata  Iam a beginner in web development. I now experienced in one year.
You are greatfull, because you are thinking client side :)