# Bootstrap dropdown not showing inside marquee

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to display bootstrap dropdown while marquee is running, but it does not show up as if it's hiding behind. Here is my fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/coder1110/vqjsh48z/2/)

I have tried with this code, but it doesn't seems working for me.

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="10" direction="left" width="100%" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" onclick="this.stop();">
  <ul style="list-style:none;">
    <li class="text-center p-0 token_list_item">
      <div class="border-right px-2 border-secondary">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25/bf9763/808080?text=1" class="rounded-circle">
        <span>100</span> Test 1
        <div class="dropdown" style="display: inline-block;">
          <a href="javascript://" class="p-1 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Button</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-0 token_list_item">
      <div class="border-right px-2 border-secondary">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25/77bf63/808080?text=2" class="rounded-circle">
        <span>150</span> Test 2
        <div class="dropdown" style="display: inline-block;">
          <a href="javascript://" class="p-1 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Button</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="text-center p-0 token_list_item">
      <div class="border-right px-2 border-secondary">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25/63bfb1/808080?text=3" class="rounded-circle">
        <span>90</span> Test 3
        <div class="dropdown" style="display: inline-block;">
          <a href="javascript://" class="p-1 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Button</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</marquee>
```

Comment: [Marquee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) is an obsolete tag and should not be used in new development. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to put auto scrolling of items

Comment: This may be helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62454347/how-can-i-make-my-vertical-css-marquee-repeat/62457336#62457336